# What should I set JAVA_HOME environment variable on macOS X 10.6?

Tags: java, macos, configuration

Many Java applications that use shell scripts to configure their environment use the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to start the correct version of Java, locate JRE JARs, and so on.

In macOS X 10.6, the following paths seem to be valid for this variable

```
/Library/Java/Home
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current
```

Some of these are symlinks to the actual current VM (as defined in the Java Preference pane).

But which one should be used—or is it okay to use any of them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is JAVA\_HOME on OSX Lion (10.7) , Mountain Lion (10.8) or Mavericks (10.9)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588390/where-is-java-home-on-osx-lion-10-7-mountain-lion-10-8-or-mavericks-10-9)

Answer (score 882, accepted):

I just set `JAVA_HOME` to the output of that command, which should give you the Java path specified in your Java preferences. Here's a snippet from my `.bashrc` file, which sets this variable:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

I haven't experienced any problems with that technique.

Occasionally I do have to change the value of `JAVA_HOME` to an earlier version of Java. For example, one program I'm maintaining requires 32-bit Java 5 on OS X, so when using that program, I set `JAVA_HOME` by running:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.5)
```

For those of you who don't have `java_home` in your path add it like this.

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java_home /usr/libexec/java_home
```

**References**:

- [Oracle explains the java_home command](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-macos.htm#JSJIG-GUID-7EB4F697-F3D1-40EA-ACDF-07FA90F02D57)
- [An article for configuring the JDK in Spring Tool Suite (Eclipse
  2019) on MacOS](https://confessionsofanagilecoach.blogspot.com/2019/12/setting-jdk-in-sts-4-on-macos.html)

Comment: Snow Leopard does still have /usr/libexec/java_home. Thanks

Comment: what is this "/usr/libexec/java_home" ?

Comment: @drlobo: It's a tool for figuring out where `JAVA_HOME` is that ships with Macs.

Comment: Still valid for Mavericks

Comment: I like to conditionalize it (in zsh) with `if /usr/libexec/java_home &> /dev/null; then export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home); fi`, so I can use the same .rc file on multiple machines whether they have the JDK installed or not. Unconditionalized; you'll get a warning on each shell startup.

Comment: In Mavericks I had to put it in `~/.bash_profile` instead of `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: thanks especially for the part with the -v extension ;)

Comment: If you want to share this environment variable with all users, you must update /etc/profile

Comment: Still valid for Yosemite. ;)

Comment: I get an error when setting the path: `ln: /usr/libexec/java_home: Operation not permitted`. Anybody knows what could be the problem?

Comment: I have multiple versions installed. I did what you wrote but it still shows the newest version. Running on El Capitan. Like someone else posted elsewhere, if you don't want it using the newest version, then you will have to rename the directory where it is installed, move it elsewhere or delete it. Seriously, this is 2016 and nobody has bothered to post a comment here on this???

Comment: For fish shell users, use something like the following: `alias java7 "set -gx JAVA_HOME (/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.7)"` (Works on El Capitan)

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: @JakeStoeffler I think that's true for all versions of mac. I'm on Sierra right now

Comment: I can not FIND Java path anywhere for Java 8 Update 121. (macOS 10.12.3)  Any ideas?

Comment: Works for High Sierra 10.13.1 with modification of version to 9.0 (possibly due to Homebrew)

Comment: High Sierra 10.13.1 check!!

Comment: Works on High Sierra 10.13.4

Comment: Still valid for Mojave

Comment: Still valid for Mojave

Comment: As mentioned by Kristopher Johnson below, this is officially documented at [Technical Q&A QA1170 - Important Java Directories on Mac OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1170/_index.html).

Comment: Remember to log in and log out, otherwise you will not see the change

Comment: Big Sur 11.2.1 check!

Answer (score 43):

Also, it`s interesting to set your PATH to reflect the JDK. After adding JAVA_HOME (which can be done with the example cited by 'mipadi'):

`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

Add also in ~/.profile:

`export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH`

**P.S.:** For OSX, I generally use .profile in the HOME dir instead of .bashrc

Comment: For OSX running default bash, I generally use the bash `.bash_profile` — why do you use than the generic `.profile`?

Comment: Since `.profile` is generic, it will work with `sh` or `bash`, while `.bash_profile` is exclusive to `bash`. Also this isolates settings from apps that use `.bash_profile`, like `MacPorts`. But you can safely use any of the two. See more about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751252/difference-between-profile-and-bash-profile-on-snow-leopard)

Comment: — FYI, the link you provided confirms my suspicion that under bash (ie by default), use of `.bash_profile` overrides `.profile`.

Comment: @LeeGee yes, and it does that because `.bash_profile` is specific, whereas `.profile` is generic, for all `sh` variations.

Comment: Since OS/X puts a link to `java` in your `/usr/bin` there shouldn't be a need to explicitly add `$JAVA_HOME` to your path.

Answer (score 23):

I am having **MAC OS X(Sierra) 10.12.2**.

I set **JAVA_HOME** to work on **React Native**(for Android apps) by following the following steps.

- Open Terminal (Command+R, type Terminal, Hit ENTER).
- Add the following lines to **~/.bash_profile**.

  `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`
- Now run the following command. 

  `source ~/.bash_profile`
- You can check the exact value of **JAVA_HOME** by typing the following command.

  `echo $JAVA_HOME`

The value(output) returned will be something like below.

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home`

**That's it.**

Comment: This is helpful, thanks.  But I believe you missed including the last step, which is then setting JAVA_HOME to the returned value in .bashrc / .bash_profile / .zshrc / etc.  Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: It is not required. In my case, `$JAVA_HOME` refers `$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` and `$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` 
 is internally referred as `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home` by the System.

Comment: Got it.  It was required in my case.  Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

I'm on Mac OS 10.6.8

The easiest solution works for me is simply put in

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

To test whether it works, put in

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
```

it shows

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

you can also test

```
$ which java
```

Answer (score 14):

Nowadays Java seems to be installed in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`

Comment: Related: [Where is JAVA_HOME on OSX Lion (10.7) or Mountain Lion (10.8)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6588390/320399)

Answer (score 9):

I tend to use `/Library/Java/Home`.  The way the preferences pane works this should be up to date with your preferred version.

Comment: /bin . and check that it points to the /Library/java and not /System/Library/.. as that one may be outdated.

Comment: This is no longer accurate. On OS X 10.5 and later, use /usr/libexec/java_home to find the path.

Answer (score 8):

That above works not any more in YOSEMITE for GRAPHICAL APPLICATIONS! Like eclipse, or anything started with Spotlight. (.bash_profile, launchd.conf works for terminal sessions only.) 
Before starting eclipse, just open a terminal window, and give out the following command:

```
launchctl setenv JAVA_HOME /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
```

(With your installation path! Perhaps works with $(/usr/libexec/java_home) instead of the full path too.)

View the whole excellent article about the permanent solution here:
[Setting environment variables via launchd.conf no longer works in OS X Yosemite/El Capitan/macOS Sierra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite)

Answer (score 4):

Create file `~/.mavenrc`

then paste this into the file

`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

test

`mvn -v`

Comment: I like this approach, because it allows me to change the Java version very easy within the .mavenrc file.

Answer (score 3):

It is recommended to check **default terminal shell** before set **JAVA_HOME** environment variable, via following commands:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

If your default terminal is **/bin/bash** (Bash), then you should use **@hygull** method

If your default terminal is **/bin/zsh** (Z Shell), then you should set these environment variable in **~/.zshenv** file with following contents:

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"
```

Similarly, any other terminal type not mentioned above, you should set environment variable in its respective terminal env file.

This method tested working in **macOS Mojave Version 10.14.6**.

Answer (score 2):

I've found this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19582689/1467169) to help, i was having the same issue and i could fix:

My java path was here:

`/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`

and was needed to put into my `.bash_profile`:

`export JAVA_HOME=\"/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home\"`

Hope help

Answer (score 2):

As other answers note, the correct way to find the Java home directory is to use `/usr/libexec/java_home`.

The official documentation for this is in Apple's *Technical Q&A QA1170: Important Java Directories on OS X*: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1170/_index.html

Comment: This is a duplicate!

Comment: I think the inclusion of the link to official Apple documentation makes it not redundant.

But if it is, the correct action is to flag it as a Duplicate, not make a comment.

Comment: I made a comment because I cannot mark an *answer* as a duplicate. Stack Overflow only allows user to mark a *question* as a duplicate (unfortunately). The link is helpful, but I think a comment to the current answer (or just edit it with the link since you already have the capability) would be better since it concentrates all useful information in one single answer. I believe there was guideline somewhere that Stack Overflow prefers fixing current answers over writing a new one.

Answer (score 2):

For me maven seems to work off the `.mavenrc` file:

```
echo "export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)" > ~/.mavenrc
```

I'm sure I picked it up on SO too, just can't remember where.

Answer (score 2):

Skipping Terminal setup since you mentioned applications, permanent system environment variable set up (works for macOS Sierra; should work for El Capitan too):

```
launchctl setenv JAVA_HOME $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```

(this will set JAVA_HOME to the latest 1.8 JDK, chances are you have gone through serveral updates e.g. javac 1.8.0_101, javac 1.8.0_131)
Of course, change 1.8 to 1.7 or 1.6 (really?) to suit your need and your system

Answer (score 0):

MacBook Pro machine - MAC OS Ventura 13

I set JAVA_HOME to work with the following the following steps:

1. Open Command prompt/Terminal (Command+R, type Terminal in search and hit Enter)
2. Open ~/.bash_profile file (`vi ~/.bash_profile`)
3. Add/Update this lines to `~/.bash_profile` (`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`)
4. Run the following command (`source ~/.bash_profile`)
5. Verify the java home path (`echo $JAVA_HOME`)

Output: It will be similar to your java path ( `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/applejdk-17.0.5.8.2.jdk/Contents/Home`)

Answer (score -1):

For Fish Shell users, use something like the following: `alias java7 "set -gx JAVA_HOME (/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.7)"`