# Maven, JAVA_HOME w/ OS X

Tags: java, macos, maven-2

Trying to get Maven, Java, and OS X to play nice together - something I've done multiple times without issue on Linux and Windows machines. I assumed all I needed to do was download Maven, setup my environment variables and I'd be good. So here's a snippet from my .bash_profile...

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home/  
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-2.2.1  
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

The `JAVA_HOME` setting is what Apple recommends be used on [this Q&A page](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2001/qa1170.html). Yet after launching a terminal and running `mvn --version`, here's the output...

```
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 15:16:01-0400)  
Java version: 1.6.0_17  
Java home: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home  
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman  
OS name: "mac os x" version: "10.6.2" arch: "x86_64" Family: "mac"
```

Any idea why the `JAVA_HOME` I'm setting in my .bash_profile is being ignored by Maven? It's causing problems because things like `rt.jar` aren't found in the `JAVA_HOME` Maven is using. I can work around this by creating symbolic links and other hackery in the home Maven is using, but I'd rather have it work correctly since this will just blow up on me the next time Apple pushes a Java update. Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that the symbolic link "CurrentJDK" inside the versions of JavaVm.framework points to the old jdk, so when i used the following commands to set the CurrentJDK to the latest one (1.7.0_45) it works

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
sudo rm CurrentJDK
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents CurrentJDK
```

reference:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/installing-jdk-7-mac-os-x

Comment: i am getting a "Operation not permitted" for 'sudo rm CurrentJDK'. I am on El Captain

Comment: Are you sure your current user has permission to read/write this folder? Better to use administrator user

Answer (score 9):

On Mac OS X, you should use /usr/libexec/java_home to determine the correct JAVA_HOME.

See [What should I set JAVA_HOME to on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348842/what-should-i-set-java-home-to-on-osx)

Answer (score 2):

On my Mac, /Library/Java/Home is a symlink (actually the start of a chain of symlinks) that ultimately points to /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home.  So I don't think maven is ignoring anything. It's just giving you the actual location.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same setup and all works fine.  UNSET the "JAVA_HOME"  environment variable in your shell script.  The Mac install takes care of that.  You are setting it wrong anyways.

Unset it, source your file or startup shell and try again.

Answer (score -2):

well the first thing I would check is whether mvn is a script.  If it is you can see how it's sourcing the environment.  If it isn't I would look for any config files typically named .mvnrc, or something in /etc.  Of course it wouldn't hurt to RTFM!

Comment: It is a script, I can see how this block  

if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ] ; then  
  JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/${JAVA_VERSION}/Home  
fi

might affect things, but when run on it's own the $JAVA_HOME var is set so the if clause is ignored.

As for reading the manual, been done. As has searching the Maven user lists. This was my last resort before relying on hack solutions. If you don't have an answer, don't answer.