# Running ProGuard on OS X: Where is Apple's equivalent to the rt.jar?

Tags: java, macos, proguard

I'm running [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) to shrink my jar file. One of the parameters it needs is the system's runtime jar. This is at `$JAVA_HOME/lib/rt.jar` on Sun distributions, but not on Apple's Mac OS X (v10.6 (Snow Leopard) in my case).

Is there an rt.jar for OS X?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is called classes.jar and it is under /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Classes

Look here for details:

http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2003/Mar/msg01530.html

Comment: On my system (Mojave 10.14.3), there is no classes.jar except in gradle caches (~/.gradle/caches/). There *is*, however, an rt.jar in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar.

Answer (score 12):

[This blog entry](http://codebistro.com/2010/07/18/proguard-and-runtime-libraries-on-mac-os-x/) describes a relatively straight-forward way to resolve the issue without modifying the Proguard configuration.

The entry recommends that two symbolic links are created, so that `rt.jar` and `jsse.jar` exist in the path that Proguard expects them to.

Standing in the `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib` directory and running the following commands resolved the problem for me:

```
sudo ln -s ../../Classes/classes.jar rt.jar
sudo ln -s ../../Classes/jsse.jar .
```

Answer (score 4):

There's some explanation of how to get to the `rt.jar` equivalent in the [What should I set JAVA_HOME to on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348842/what-should-i-set-java-home-to-on-osx) question.

The short answer is to use the result of `/usr/libexec/java_home` or to set `JAVA_HOME` to `$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` and then find `classes.jar` (the OS X equivalent of rt.jar) at `JAVA_HOME/bundle/Classes/classes.jar`

Answer (score 1):

On my system (Mojave 10.14.3 with JDK1.8), there is no `classes.jar` except in gradle caches (`~/.gradle/caches/`). There is, however, an `rt.jar` in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar`. I linked it and `jsse.jar` in the same way as Henrik from the `Contents/Home/lib` folder:

```
➜  lib sudo ln -s ../jre/lib/rt.jar 
➜  lib sudo ln -s ../jre/lib/jsse.jar
```

and Proguard works now.

Answer (score 0):

For me the reason was I had JDK 13 installed. After installing JDK 1.8 the file appeared in the location expected by ProGuard. You can run `sudo find /Library -name rt.jar` to find the exact path to the `rt.jar` after installing JDK 1.8