# How to include rt.jar/classes.jar in Proguard configuration in an OS independant way?

Tags: java, android, proguard

As described in Proguard's [troubleshooting page](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/troubleshooting.html):

> In MacOS X, the run-time classes may be in a different place than on most other platforms. You'll then have to adapt your configuration, replacing the path `<java.home>/lib/rt.jar` by `<java.home>/../Classes/classes.jar`.

So for instance, on non-Mac environments you might have the following in your Proguard config:

```
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
```

But for Mac environments you would point to `classes.jar`.

---

This is fine if this is only ever developed on a Mac, but if this code is checked into version control and shared by developers on multiple OSs and also on a build server running a different OS, it needs to be more flexible.

Is there a way to configure this in Proguard to work no matter what OS it runs on, without requiring users of the code to [make filesystem changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11830154/445348)?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a system variable that depends on the environment and use that:

```
-libraryjars <runtime.jar>
```

However, if you are developing for Android:

- You should not refer to `rt.jar` or `classes.jar`, since they contain many java runtime classes that are not present in the Android runtime.
- You should not specify `-libraryjars`, since the Ant/Eclipse/Gradle build processes already automatically specify all necessary `-injars`, `-outjars`, and `-libraryjars` for you.

If you see warnings about missing java runtime classes, you should consider an option like `-dontwarn javax.**`. See the ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Warning: can't find referenced class](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass).