# Where is JAVA_HOME on macOS Mojave (10.14) to Lion (10.7)?

Tags: java, macos

Java is an optional package on the latest versions of macOS.

Yet once installed it appears like the **JAVA_HOME** environment variable is **not set properly**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I set JAVA\_HOME to on OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348842/what-should-i-set-java-home-to-on-osx)

Comment: On Mac Sierra I've /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines which has jdk and System Preferences > Java what's different between these 2 ?

Comment: Don't underestimate the chances that your Java installation may not have completed properly. If none of the below excellent suggestions seem to work, try [re]installing!

Answer (score 1096, accepted):

With the [Java optional package](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=en_US) or [Oracle JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads) installed,
adding one of the following lines to your **~/.bash_profile** file will set the environment variable accordingly.

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6)"
or
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)"
or
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)"
or simply
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"
```

Note: If you installed *openjdk* on mac using **brew**, run  `sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk` for the above to work

Update: added **-v** flag based on *Jilles van Gurp* [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11967738/752167).

Comment: Does this only take care or the CLI? I know in 10.5 and below if you need to set a custom location (outside of the normal structure) you often need to to edit the ~/.MacOSX for GUI launched apps.

Comment: Good to know. I have to say im not too thrilled with the feature list for Lion. There doesnt seem to much there in the way of enhancements for my usage...

Comment: @Oliver: ewww :-) Thats probably the least useful thing... i always have multiple windows opened and arranged on screen so i can see multiple things at once... usually a different layout on every space.

Comment: this didn't work for me. /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home worked.

Comment: The backticks were my undoing. This worked after copying and pasting properly :)

Comment: Works on Maverick, too!

Comment: For me @chaostheory's solution worked. On OSX Mavericks.

Comment: how come /usr/libexec/java_home -V doesn't show me java 1.8 that I just installed and is available on /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin

Comment: @chaostheory I tried this but it says "... is a directory"

Comment: It's an issue actually, we shouldn't be forced to change our dotfiles in Yosemite to use Java JRE. Installing JDK solves the problem (no changes to .*profile files required) however again, we shouldnt be forced to install ~500MB JDK just to run stuff that requires much smaller JRE (like SquirrelSQL).

Comment: Works on Yosemite. Be careful with the ticking as what @loeschg mentioned, copy & paste does the trick.

Comment: Worked for me. I had to restart Terminal before the difference took effect.

Comment: also found this link which may help as well: https://gist.github.com/johan/10590467

Comment: Works on Mac OS X High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: For Java 11 and High Sierra, export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11)"

Comment: The double quotes are not required

Answer (score 125):

`/usr/libexec/java_home` is not a directory but an executable. It outputs the currently configured JAVA_HOME and doesn't actually change it. That's what the Java Preferences app is for, which in my case seems broken and doesn't actually change the JVM correctly. It does list the 1.7 JVM but I can toggle/untoggle & drag and drop all I want there without actually changing the output of `/usr/libexec/java_home`.

Even after installing 1.7.0 u6 from Oracle on Lion and setting it as the default in the preferences, it still returned the apple 1.6 java home. The only fix that actually works for me is setting JAVA_HOME manually:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_06.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

At least this way when run from the command line it will use 1.7. `/usr/libexec/java_home` still insists on 1.6.

**Update**: [Understanding Java From Command Line on OSX](http://web.archive.org/web/20140813164713/http://blog.hgomez.net/blog/2012/07/20/understanding-java-from-command-line-on-osx/) has a better explanation on how this works.

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
```

is the way to do it. Note, updating this to 1.8 works just fine.

Comment: blog.hgomez.net/2012/07 is broken _but_ it's fixed in the answer which now links to http://web.archive.org/web/20140813164713/http://blog.hgomez.net/blog/2012/07/20/understanding-java-from-command-line-on-osx/

Comment: export JAVA_HOME="/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8"

Answer (score 84):

For me, Mountain Lion 10.8.2, the solution most voted does not work.
I installed jdk 1.7 via Oracle and maven from homebrew.

My solution is from the hadoop-env.sh file of hadoop which I installed from homebrew, too.
I add the below sentence in ~/.bash_profile, and it works.

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"
```

This solution also works for OS X Yosemite with Java 1.8 installed from Oracle.

Comment: It would have worked if you had installed java 6 from Apple. the point here is that you are using oracle java 7.

Comment: This works for me on Mavricks very well but the location of the java_home script is different.    `export JAVA_HOME="$(/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java_home)"`

Comment: I tried to set up maven on mac Yosemite, this way to set JAVA_HOME works for me.

Comment: Works for me on Sierra 10.12 and Java 8

Answer (score 44):

None of the above answers helped me. I suppose all the answers are for older `OS X`

For OS X Yosemite 10.10, follow these steps

Use your favorite text editor to open: `~/.bash_profile`

```
//This command will open the file using vim
$ vim ~/.bash_profile
```

Add the following line in the file and save it ( : followed by "x" for vim):

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Then in the terminal type the following two commands to see output:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
```

In the second line, you are updating the contents of `.bash_profile` file.

Comment: I think I got your pb - you use quotes instead of backquotes  ' vs `

Comment: No i'm using the right quotes, instead I tried copy pasting, it didn't work. I updated my answer because it worked for me.

Comment: @OlivierRefalo I can see you've updated your answer with double quotes("). But even without quotes, it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot . It worked for me to in Yosemite 10.10

Comment: This is the only solution, that really works. Adding path by any other solution, will add on temporary basis, until you terminate the terminal, and the path vanishes. To be added permanently, the path must be saved in .bash_profile file. Meanwhile, I used nano rather than vim, for the simplicity.

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
 cordova requirements

Java JDK: not installed

Answer (score 36):

Update for Java 9 and some neat aliases.

In `.bash_profile`:

```sh
export JAVA_HOME8=`/usr/libexec/java_home --version 1.8`
export JAVA_HOME9=`/usr/libexec/java_home --version 9`
```

Note, that for the latest version it is `9` and not `1.9`.

Set active Java:

```sh
export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME8
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Some additional alias to switch between the different versions:

```sh
alias j8='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME8; export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH'
alias j9='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME9; export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH'
```

Test in terminal:

```sh
% j8
% java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
% j9
% java -version
java version "9"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)
```

EDIT: Update for Java 10

```sh
export JAVA_HOME10=`/usr/libexec/java_home --version 10`
alias j10='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME10; export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH'
```

EDIT: Update for Java 11

```sh
export JAVA_HOME11=`/usr/libexec/java_home --version 11`
alias j11='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME11; export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH'
```

Answer (score 30):

The above didn't work for me with Amazon's EC2 tools, because it expects `bin/java` etc. underneath `JAVA_HOME`. `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home` did work.

Comment: Was it lion ? did you get the official Java package from Apple, or Java6/7 from Oracle ?

Comment: I believe it was Apple's Java package.

Comment: @AndrewH yes I found the same to be true.  Installed Apple's Java package and discovered the actual library path (for example, to set -vm in eclipse.ini): /System/Library/Java/Support/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/javaws.jar

Comment: Thanks for the info. Maybe I'm too simple, but why does OS X make such a simple thing a complete mess?

Answer (score 19):

For OS X you can do:

```sh
export JAVA_HOME=`/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java_home`
```

Comment: Of note, HFS+ is case insensitive.

Answer (score 15):

On Mac OS X Lion, to set visualgc to run, I used:

```bsh
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home
```

Comment: I don't get your proposal: how is that different from export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`  ? the command /usr/libexec/java_home returns 
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: For visualgc /usr/libexec/java_home yields:

The java.exe found at:
/usr/libexec/java_home
is not in a JDK directory. Please set and export your
JVMSTAT_JAVA_HOME environment variable to refer to a
directory containing the Sun J2SE 1.5.0 JDK (not a JRE)
and try again.

Answer (score 15):

The following worked for me. I'm using ZSH on OSX Yosemite with Java 8 installed.

The following command `/usr/libexec/java_home` emits the path to JDK home:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home`

In your `~/.zshrc`,

```
export JAVA_HOME = "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Comment: How is that different that the proposed solution?

Comment: It's not different to the proposed solution. This solution is specific to people using ZSH, Java 8 and OSX Yosemite.

Comment: Confirmed working like a charm with java 1.8 installed on OSX Yosemite, cheers mate.

Comment: The general solution works just fine for Java 8, zsh, and Yosemite.

Answer (score 13):

for macOS Mojave 10.14.1 and JAVA 11.0.1
I set the profile as

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

key in terminal this to confirm:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version

java version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Works on Catalina. Ty

Answer (score 11):

A better (more upgradable) way is to use the following:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home
```

This should work with AWS also since it has `bin` underneath Home

Comment: kind of disagree with that statement "more upgradable"  /usr/libexec/java_home is an exe that returns a path,not a fixed path. Besides depending on what jvm version you use, the path above won't match

Answer (score 11):

Newer Oracle JVMs such as 1.7.0_21-b12 seem to install here:

`/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`

Comment: Indeed - and the `/usr/libexec/java_home` tool returns an error for these Java versions.

Comment: This is THE only answer working for me after downloading v1.7 JRE

Comment: This is the path if you install the JRE. Most of the rated answers and comments are about the JDK. Not the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

My approach is:

.bashrc

```
export JAVA6_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6`
export JAVA7_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA6_HOME

# -- optional
# export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

This makes it very easy to switch between J6 and J7

Answer (score 5):

I Had to explicitly set it to the exact path on my Macbook air .

Steps followed:

1. try to `echo $JAVA_HOME` (if it's set it'll show the path), if not, try to search for it using `sudo find /usr/ -name *jdk`
2. Edit the Bash p with - `sudo nano ~/.bash_profile`
3. Add the exact path to JAVA Home (with the path from step 2 above)
   `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home`
4. Save and exit
5. Check JAVA_Home using - `echo $JAVA_HOME`

I am running MACOS MOJAVE - 10.14.2 (18C54) on a Macbook Air with JAVA 8

Answer (score 3):

For Mac OS X  10.9  I installed the latest version of JRE from Oracle and then reset the JAVA_HOME to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home.

I am sure there is a better way but this got me up and running.

hughsmac:~ hbrien$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: On a fresh Mavericks install, this is the only solution that worked for me. Had to point sqldeveloper to the jdk home located here (as suggested by [this thread](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2596908) to get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

OSX Yosemite, ZSH, and Java SE Runtime Environment 8, I had to:

`$ sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/bin`

and in ~/.zshrc change JAVA_HOME to 
`export JAVA_HOME="/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current"`

Answer (score 2):

For Java 11 (JDK 11) it can be located with the following command:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue after I upgrade my Mac OS and following worked for me:

1. cmd>vi ~/.bash_profile
2. Add/update the line for JAVA_HOME:
   export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_15.jdk/Contents/Home"
3. cmd>source ~/.bash_profile or open a new terminal

I think the jdk version might differ, so just use the version which you have under /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/

Answer (score 1):

If you are in need to have multiple versions of JDK under Mac OS X (Yosemite), it might be helpful to add some scripting for automated switching between them.

What you do is to edit your **~/.bash_profile** and add the following:

```
function setjdk() {
  if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
   removeFromPath '/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/bin'
   if [ -n "${JAVA_HOME+x}" ]; then
    removeFromPath $JAVA_HOME
   fi
   export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v $@`
   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
  fi
 }
 function removeFromPath() {
  export PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed -E -e "s;:$1;;" -e "s;$1:?;;")
 }
setjdk 1.7
```

What the script does is to first remove other JDK versions in the **PATH** so that they won’t interfere with our new JDK version. Then it makes some clever use of **/usr/libexec/java_home** which is a command that lists installed JDK versions. The **-v** argument tells **java_home** to return the path of the JDK with the supplied version, for example 1.7. We also update the **PATH** to point to the bin directory of the newly found **JAVA_HOME** directory. At the end we can simply execute the function using

```
setjdk 1.7
```

which selects the latest installed JDK version of the 1.7 branch. To select a specific version you can simply execute

```
setjdk 1.7.0_51
```

instead. Run **/usr/libexec/java_home -V** to get more details on how to choose versions.

P.S. Do not forget to  **source ~/.bash_profile** after you save it.

Answer (score 1):

For Fish terminal users on Mac (I believe it's available on Linux as well), this should work:

```
set -Ux JAVA_8 (/usr/libexec/java_home --version 1.8)
set -Ux JAVA_12 (/usr/libexec/java_home --version 12)
set -Ux JAVA_HOME $JAVA_8       //or whichever version you want as default
```

Answer (score 1):

Handy command for knowing java home and other details.

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version
```

and to know all java homes on your mac:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

Comment: I recently figured this one out myself and came looking here to share to find you already discovered; had posted on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1479533/1715621)
This is a good solution if `java` is on the `PATH` but when some tool/application actually needs `JAVA_HOME` set.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is related to **Mountain Lion** and not Lion. I needed to do this for the AWS Command Line Tools. According to [the AWS docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SettingUp_CommandLine.html#java-runtime), running `which java` returns `/usr/bin/java`.

So, I set `JAVA_HOME=/usr` in my `.bashrc`.

Apparently, `/usr/bin/java` is a symbolic link to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java` which makes it all work.

**Update**

As mentioned in the comment below, this `JAVA_HOME` value is not an ideal solution when the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is to be used by things other than the AWS Command Line Tools. It works fine for the AWS Command Line Tools, though, as given in their docs.

Comment: the point is, /usr is not a correct JAVA_HOME directory. It's ok to locate bin/java. But sometimes builders (ant, make) use JAVA_HOME to reference the javac compiler in lib/tools.jar    Your solution will fail for those

Answer (score 0):

for mac user .
java 8  should  add

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
# JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home
```

java 6 :

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6`
# JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

ref :http://qiita.com/seri_k/items/e978c1339ce51f13e297

Answer (score 0):

For Mac Yosemite,

JDK 1.7.0_xx is using

```
$ ls -ltar /usr/bin/java
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java

JAVA_HOME

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_xx.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: Can you please add more information to make this answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone using AUSKEY from the Australian Tax Office (ATO) should uninstall AUSKEY. 
This sorted out my JAVA_HOME issues.

It is also no longer required for MAC users. Yah!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Fish](https://fishshell.com/) shell on High Sierra 10.13.4 and installed Java via Brew.

It's not automatically set up so to set it [correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30187924/170239) on my system I run:

```
set -U JAVA_HOME (/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set java_home of 1.8 jdk version in `netbeans.conf` file:

```
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf
```

uncomment line:

```
netbeans_jdkhome="path/to/jdk"
```

and set path to your 1.8 jdk, in my case:

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

This approach lays you to have several jdk versions on mac os