# How to install unlimited strength JCE for JRE 7 in MacOSX?

Tags: java, macos, jce

I installed Oracle JRE 7 (not JDK) for MacOSX but I can't locate where the JCE jurisdiction files are placed.

I need to replace them with the unlimited strength version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179672/unlimited-strength-jce-policy-files

Comment: This is not a duplicate because JRE 7 seems to not have a Java Home, or I'm not able to find it... This is my problem.

Comment: A two second Google (for the terms `macosx java home`) found this site: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1170/_index.html. Have you researched this at all before asking?

Comment: This is the path for the JDK Java Home not JRE. Have you read before commenting?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your comment on [Thom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24618/thom)'s answer is correct. The JRE path is `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/`, and the JCE files are then under `lib/security/`.

I happen to have multiple JVMs installed, so I thought it was worth showing a way to check whether a particular JVM has the correct files. These are some commands you can use to determine whether a given Java installation is configured correctly:

```
find ~/Downloads/UnlimitedJCEPolicy -name *.jar |xargs md5
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/  # -OR-
cd '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/'
find . \( -name local_policy.jar -or -name US_export_policy.jar \) |xargs md5
```

Once you know the path to the files, you can replace them as-needed. Keep in mind that each version of Java may require different JCE libraries. You may need separate jars for 6, 7, and 8, depending on compatibility.

Answer (score 32):

I've installed the Oracle JDK, and if it helps, the directory in my case was `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/`. Your mileage may vary, in which case just run `find . -name local_policy.jar` and see what it turns up.

Comment: I found 2:

./Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/security/local_policy.jar

./Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/local_policy.jar

I think the firs is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 26):

**This is for the JDK, not the JRE**.

---

I'm on a Mac, OSx Lion and I used [`/usr/libexec/java_home`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6588410/761771) to find my java home

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
# Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
#     1.7.0_51, x86_64: "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
#     1.6.0_65-b14-462, x86_64: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
#     1.6.0_65-b14-462, i386:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
# 
# /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home

/usr/libexec/java_home
# /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home

/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6
# /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7
# /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
```

From here you can use this executable and find to locate these files

```
find $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7) -name local_policy.jar
# /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/local_policy.jar

find $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7) -name US_export_policy.jar
# /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/US_export_policy.jar
```

And combine that with @ngreen's answer to get the md5 of these files (if you want)

```
find ~/Downloads/UnlimitedJCEPolicy -name *.jar |xargs md5
# MD5 (/Users/nperry/Downloads/UnlimitedJCEPolicy/local_policy.jar) = 9dd69bcc7637d872121880c35437788d
# MD5 (/Users/nperry/Downloads/UnlimitedJCEPolicy/US_export_policy.jar) = 3bb2e88a915b3cb003ca185357a92c16

find $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7) -name local_policy.jar | xargs md5
# MD5 (/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/local_policy.jar) = f41ab8f64b1fa13fec7276579c420951

find $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7) -name US_export_policy.jar | xargs md5
# MD5 (/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/US_export_policy.jar) = d5d126ae15abecb7d6e3a28b0d57543e
```

And you can see I have not replaced these files yet.

Backup the original files if you want

```
mkdir ~/Downloads/JCEPolicy-originals-1.7/
cp $(find $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7) -name local_policy.jar)     ~/Downloads/JCEPolicy-originals-1.7/
cp $(find $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7) -name US_export_policy.jar) ~/Downloads/JCEPolicy-originals-1.7/
```

You can replace the files with this.

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/UnlimitedJCEPolicy/local_policy.jar $(find $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7) -name local_policy.jar)
sudo cp ~/Downloads/UnlimitedJCEPolicy/US_export_policy.jar $(find $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7) -name US_export_policy.jar)
```

And getting the MD5s tells me if it worked

```
find $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7) -name local_policy.jar | xargs md5
# MD5 (/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/local_policy.jar) = 9dd69bcc7637d872121880c35437788d

find $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7) -name US_export_policy.jar | xargs md5
# MD5 (/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/US_export_policy.jar) = 3bb2e88a915b3cb003ca185357a92c16
```

Comment: This is the JDK not the JRE.