# Running simple JUnit tests on Android Studio (IntelliJ) when using a Gradle-based configuration

Tags: android, junit, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

I am using `Android Studio/IntelliJ` to build on an existing `Android` project and would like to add some simple `JUnit` unit tests. What is the right folder to add such tests on?

The android `Gradle` plug-in defines a directory structure with `src/main/java` for the main source code and `src/instrumentTest/java` for `Android` tests.

Trying to add my JUnit tests in instrumentTest didn't work for me. I can run it as an `Android` test (that's what that directory seems for) but that's not what I'm looking for - I just want to run a simple `JUnit` test.
I tried creating a JUnit run configuration for this Class but that also didn't work - I'm supposing because I'm using a directory that is flagged as `Android` Test instead of Source.

If I create a new source folder and marki it as such in Project Structure, this will get wiped next time `IntelliJ` refreshes the project configuration from the gradle build files.

What is the more appropriate way of configuring JUnit tests in an gradle-based android project on `IntelliJ`? Which directory structure to use for this?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help you with the tests as I'm still struggling with this myself, but you can use this to stop IntelliJ wiping the source folders: `java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java','src/instrumentTest/java']` in the `sourceSets` section of the `build.gradle`

Comment: Its not fun to set up, nor simple to maintain, but I somehow got it running using the default `/src/androidTest/java` folder with robolectric JUnit tests, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25473702/1406325

Comment: Android Studio now supports Local Unit Testing with JUnit 4: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30273301/885464

Comment: @Julian Cerruti Update:Android Studio Demo for how to run testcase http://goo.gl/ac06C0 and example to run network call test http://goo.gl/bQFlmU

Comment: The directories structures for tests and tested classes must fit. Here is how to do it easily: stackoverflow.com/a/36057080/715269

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As of Android Studio 1.1, the answer is now simple:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support

Comment: Does this mean that Robolectric is no longer useful? Will this essentially do the same thing?

Comment: Note: As of Android Studio 2.0 Beta5 the in the link describe "Test Artifact" selector is missing and both modes (junit & insttrumentation) are enabled simultaneously by default. See here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708263/test-artifact-selector-missing-gone-from-build-variants-in-android-studio-2-beta

Comment: Please stop posting links as an answer. The link is dead.

Answer (score 36):

Normally, you can't. Welcome to the world of Android, where all tests must run on a device(except Robolectric).

The main reason is that you don't actually have the framework's sources - even if you convince the IDE to run the test locally, you will immediately get a "Stub! Not implemented" exception.
"Why?" you might wonder? Because the `android.jar` that the SDK gives you is actually all stubbed out - all the classes and methods are there but they all just throw an exception. It's there to provide an API but not there to give you any actual implementation.

There's a wonderful project called [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) which implements a lot of the framework just so you can run meaningful tests. Coupled with a good mock framework (e.g., Mockito), it makes your job manageable.

Gradle plugin: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin

Comment: Thank you, Deylan. I am after simple tests that do not use any Android infrastructure, so either creating a new project like you suggest or tweaking the Gradle Android configuration to accommodate regular tests will be the route to go. Unfortunately I still wasn't able to get  it to work - it keeps failing for one reason or another - but will post the result if I ever get it to work

Comment: In that case, you want to make a new plain java Gradle project (i.e. `apply plugin: 'java'`), add it to 'settings.gradle', have it as a dependency to your Android project (`compile project(':plainJavaProjectName')`), and just run the `test` task. (Not tested but should definitely work!)

Comment: Tests in a plain java gradle project work fine with command line, but not inside Android Studio where I'm getting a "class not found MyTestClass" error. That's strange because AS and the command line should use gradle the same way.

Comment: lukas: did you find a fix for that? I'm stuck at the same situation. Class not found running for AS.

Comment: Avoid gradle if you want to use JUnit testing, maven is a better option.

Comment: Can you justify that statement?  Why is Maven better?

Comment: Android Studio is catching up slowly, see the recent beta:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support

Comment: Android Studio now supports Local Unit Testing with JUnit 4: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30273301/885464

Answer (score 32):

## Intro

Note that at the time of writing robolectric 2.4 is the latest version and has no support for `appcompat v7` library. Support wil be added in robolectric 3.0 release (*no ETA yet*). Also `ActionBar Sherlock` can cause issues with robolectric.

To use Robolectric within Android Studio you have 2 options:

## (Option 1) - Running JUnit tests with Android Studio using a Java module

This technique uses a java module for all your tests with a dependency to your android module and a custom test runner with some magic:

Instructions can be found here: http://blog.blundellapps.com/how-to-run-robolectric-junit-tests-in-android-studio/

Also check the link at the end of that post for running the tests from android studio.

## (Option 2) - Running JUnit Tests with Android Studio using robolectric-gradle-plugin

I encountered a few issues setting up junit tests to run from gradle in Android Studio.

This is a very basic sample project for running junit tests from a gradle based project in Android Studio: https://github.com/hanscappelle/android-studio-junit-robolectric This was tested with Android Studio 0.8.14, JUnit 4.10, robolectric gradle plugin 0.13+ and robolectric 2.3

### Buildscript (project/build.gradle)

The build script is the build.gradle file in the root of you project. There I had to add [robolectric gradle plugin](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin) to classpath

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:0.13.+'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

### Project buildscript (App/build.gradle)

In the build script of your app module use the `robolectric` plugin, add `robolectric` config and add `androidTestCompile` dependencies.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'robolectric'

android {
    // like any other project
}

robolectric {
    // configure the set of classes for JUnit tests
    include '**/*Test.class'
    exclude '**/espresso/**/*.class'

    // configure max heap size of the test JVM
    maxHeapSize = '2048m'

    // configure the test JVM arguments
    jvmArgs '-XX:MaxPermSize=512m', '-XX:-UseSplitVerifier'

    // configure whether failing tests should fail the build
    ignoreFailures true

    // use afterTest to listen to the test execution results
    afterTest { descriptor, result ->
        println "Executing test for {$descriptor.name} with result: ${result.resultType}"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
}
```

### Create JUnit Test Classes

Now put the test classes in the default location (or update gradle config)

```
app/src/androidTest/java
```

And name your tests classes ending with Test (or again update config), extending `junit.framework.TestCase` and annotate test methods with `@Test`.

```
package be.hcpl.android.mytestedapplication;

import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MainActivityTest extends TestCase {

    @Test
    public void testThatSucceeds(){
        // all OK
        assert true;
    }

    @Test
    public void testThatFails(){
        // all NOK
        assert false;
    }
}
```

### Execute Tests

Next execute the tests using gradlew from command line (make it executable using `chmod +x` if needed)

```
./gradlew clean test
```

Sample output:

```
Executing test for {testThatSucceeds} with result: SUCCESS
Executing test for {testThatFails} with result: FAILURE

android.hcpl.be.mytestedapplication.MainActivityTest > testThatFails FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at MainActivityTest.java:21

2 tests completed, 1 failed                                  
There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///Users/hcpl/Development/git/MyTestedApplication/app/build/test-report/debug/index.html
:app:test                      

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

### Troubleshooting

#### alternative source directories

Just like you can have your java source files somewhere else you can move your test source files. Just update gradle `sourceSets` config.

```
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        androidTest {
            setRoot('tests')
        }
    }
```

#### package org.junit does not exist

You forgot to add the junit test dependency in the app build script

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
}
```

#### java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!

You're running this test with the run configurations from Android Studio instead of command line (Terminal tab in Android Studio). To run it from Android Studio you'll have to update the `app.iml` file to have the jdk entry listed at the bottom. See [deckard-gradle example](https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle) for details.

Complete error example:

```
!!! JUnit version 3.8 or later expected:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.<init>(BaseTestRunner.java:5)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:54)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:48)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:41)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.junitVersionChecks(JUnitStarter.java:190)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.canWorkWithJUnitVersion(JUnitStarter.java:173)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

#### ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588390/where-is-java-home-on-osx-yosemite-10-10-mavericks-10-9-mountain-lion-10) for a solution. Add the below export to you bash profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
```

The complete error log:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

#### Test Class not found

If you want to run your tests from Android Studio Junit Test runner instead you'll have to expand the build.gradle file a little more so that android studio can find your compiled test classes:

```
sourceSets {
    testLocal {
        java.srcDir file('src/test/java')
        resources.srcDir file('src/test/resources')
    }
}

android {

    // tell Android studio that the instrumentTest source set is located in the unit test source set
    sourceSets {
        instrumentTest.setRoot('src/test')
    }
}

dependencies {

    // Dependencies for the `testLocal` task, make sure to list all your global dependencies here as well
    testLocalCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testLocalCompile 'com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4'
    testLocalCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3'

    // Android Studio doesn't recognize the `testLocal` task, so we define the same dependencies as above for instrumentTest
    // which is Android Studio's test task
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4'
    androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3'

}

task localTest(type: Test, dependsOn: assemble) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.testLocal.output.classesDir

    android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each { dir ->
        def buildDir = dir.getAbsolutePath().split('/')
        buildDir =  (buildDir[0..(buildDir.length - 4)] + ['build', 'classes', 'debug']).join('/')

        sourceSets.testLocal.compileClasspath += files(buildDir)
        sourceSets.testLocal.runtimeClasspath += files(buildDir)
    }

    classpath = sourceSets.testLocal.runtimeClasspath
}

check.dependsOn localTest
```

from: http://kostyay.name/android-studio-robolectric-gradle-getting-work/

### Some more resources

The best articles I found around this are:

- http://tryge.com/2013/02/28/android-gradle-build/
- http://kostyay.name/android-studio-robolectric-gradle-getting-work/
- http://www.element84.com/easy-testing-with-android-studio.html
- http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Sourcesets-and-Dependencies

Comment: URLs for the first 2 links seem to have changed. Here are working ones: [Option 1](https://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/how-to-run-robolectric-junit-tests-in-android-studio/), [Option 2](https://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/android-gradle-app-with-robolectric-junit-tests/)

Answer (score 3):

This is now supported in Android Studio starting with Android Gradle plugin 1.1.0, check this out:

https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html

Sample app with local unit tests on GitHub:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/tree/master/unittesting/BasicSample

Comment: The github link is not available

Answer (score 1):

For **Android Studio 1.2+** setting up a project for **JUnit is pretty simple** try to follow along this tutorial:

This is the simplest part setting up a project for JUnit:

https://io2015codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/android-studio-testing#1

Follow along the past link until "[Running your tests](https://io2015codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/android-studio-testing#5)"

Now if you want to integrate with intrumentation test follow along from here:

https://io2015codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/android-studio-testing#6

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html) from the Android Developers official site. This article also shows how to create mock-ups for your testing.

By the way, you should note that the scope of the dependencies for simple JUnit test should be "testCompile".