# Gradle + Robolectric: Where do I put the file org.robolectric.Config.properties?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, gradle, robolectric

I'm trying to setup a test using Robolectric to click on a menu button in [this repository](https://github.com/robhawkins/frontlinesms-for-android/).  Basic Robolectric tests will run, but I'm not able to run any project-specific test using resources because it says it can't find my AndroidManifest.xml.  After running `../gradlew clean check`, here's the standard output from the Robolectric html file:

`WARNING: No manifest file found at ./AndroidManifest.xml.Falling back to the Android OS resources only.
To remove this warning, annotate your test class with @Config(manifest=Config.NONE).`

I found [these instructions](http://robolectric.blogspot.com/2013/05/configuring-robolectric-20.html) which indicate I should create an `org.robolectric.Config.properties` file, but I'm not sure where to put it.  I've tried everywhere, pretty much, and despite moving the file, the path in the error message is always the same as above (./AndroidManifest.xml).  This makes me think the build process has never picked up the settings in the file `org.robolectric.Config.properties`.

I also tried the @Config(manifest="") directive but this gave me a `cannot find symbol` error.  If I move the AndroidManifest.xml into my project directory, then I get an error about it not being able to find the path `./res/values` and I wasn't able to resolve that either.  Any ideas?

**Update 1**

Thanks Eugen, I'm now using `@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)` instead of `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner)`.

Now I get a different error, still occurring on the same line of [my BasicTest.java](https://github.com/robhawkins/frontlinesms-for-android/blob/master/FrontlineSMS/src/test/java/net/frontlinesms/android/BasicTest.java)

```
KeywordList keywordList = Robolectric.buildActivity(KeywordList.class).create().get();
```

Below are results from the standard error, standard output, and "failed tests" tab in the Robolectric test report:

Note: I also tried substituting in a jar built from the latest Robolectric updates, robolectric-2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar, but still got an error.

*Standard Error*

`WARNING: no system properties value for ro.build.date.utc`

*Standard Output*

```
DEBUG: Loading resources for net.frontlinesms.android from ~/workspace-studio/frontlinesms-for-android/FrontlineSMS/build/res/all/debug...
DEBUG: Loading resources for android from jar:~/.m2/repository/org/robolectric/android-res/4.1.2_r1_rc/android-res-4.1.2_r1_rc-real.jar!/res...
INFO: no id mapping found for android:drawable/scrollbar_handle_horizontal; assigning ID #0x1140002
INFO: no id mapping found for android:drawable/scrollbar_handle_vertical; assigning ID #0x1140003
INFO: no id mapping found for android:color/highlighted_text_dark; assigning ID #0x1140004
INFO: no id mapping found for android:color/hint_foreground_dark; assigning ID #0x1140005
INFO: no id mapping found for android:color/link_text_dark; assigning ID #0x1140006
INFO: no id mapping found for android:color/dim_foreground_dark_disabled; assigning ID #0x1140007
INFO: no id mapping found for android:color/dim_foreground_dark; assigning ID #0x1140008
INFO: no id mapping found for android:color/dim_foreground_dark_inverse_disabled; assigning ID #0x1140009
INFO: no id mapping found for android:color/dim_foreground_dark_inverse; assigning ID #0x114000a
INFO: no id mapping found for android:color/bright_foreground_dark_inverse; assigning ID #0x114000b
INFO: no id mapping found for android:layout/text_edit_paste_window; assigning ID #0x114000c
INFO: no id mapping found for android:layout/text_edit_no_paste_window; assigning ID #0x114000d
INFO: no id mapping found for android:layout/text_edit_side_paste_window; assigning ID #0x114000e
INFO: no id mapping found for android:layout/text_edit_side_no_paste_window; assigning ID #0x114000f
INFO: no id mapping found for android:layout/text_edit_suggestion_item; assigning ID #0x1140010
```

*Failed Tests*

```
android.view.InflateException: XML file ~/workspace-studio/frontlinesms-for-android/FrontlineSMS/build/res/all/debug/layout/rule_list.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class net.frontlinesms.android.ui.view.ActionBar
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at org.robolectric.tester.android.view.RoboWindow.setContentView(RoboWindow.java:82)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.setContentView(ShadowActivity.java:272)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java)
at net.frontlinesms.android.activity.KeywordList.onCreate(KeywordList.java:70)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
at org.fest.reflect.method.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:112)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:119)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:256)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:114)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:126)
at net.frontlinesms.android.BasicTest.setUp(BasicTest.java:30)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:241)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:47)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:49)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:103)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:355)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
at org.robolectric.tester.android.view.RoboWindow.setContentView(RoboWindow.java:82)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.setContentView(ShadowActivity.java:272)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.robolectric.bytecode.ShadowWrangler$ShadowMethodPlan.run(ShadowWrangler.java:455)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java)
at net.frontlinesms.android.activity.KeywordList.onCreate(KeywordList.java:70)
at android.app.Activity.$$robo$$Activity_c57b_performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.fest.reflect.method.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:112)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:119)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:256)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:114)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:126)
at net.frontlinesms.android.BasicTest.setUp(BasicTest.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:241)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:47)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:103)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
... 7 more
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: XML file ~/workspace-studio/frontlinesms-for-android/FrontlineSMS/build/res/all/debug/layout/actionbar.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class android.widget.ProgressBar
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
at org.robolectric.shadows.RoboLayoutInflater.onCreateView(RoboLayoutInflater.java:38)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at net.frontlinesms.android.ui.view.ActionBar.<init>(ActionBar.java:65)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at org.robolectric.tester.android.view.RoboWindow.setContentView(RoboWindow.java:82)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.setContentView(ShadowActivity.java:272)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java)
at net.frontlinesms.android.activity.KeywordList.onCreate(KeywordList.java:70)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
at org.fest.reflect.method.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:112)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:119)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:256)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:114)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:126)
at net.frontlinesms.android.BasicTest.setUp(BasicTest.java:30)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:241)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:47)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:49)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:103)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java)
at org.robolectric.shadows.RoboLayoutInflater.onCreateView(RoboLayoutInflater.java:38)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
at net.frontlinesms.android.ui.view.ActionBar.<init>(ActionBar.java:65)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
at org.robolectric.tester.android.view.RoboWindow.setContentView(RoboWindow.java:82)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.setContentView(ShadowActivity.java:272)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.robolectric.bytecode.ShadowWrangler$ShadowMethodPlan.run(ShadowWrangler.java:455)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java)
at net.frontlinesms.android.activity.KeywordList.onCreate(KeywordList.java:70)
at android.app.Activity.$$robo$$Activity_c57b_performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.fest.reflect.method.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:112)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:119)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:256)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:114)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:126)
at net.frontlinesms.android.BasicTest.setUp(BasicTest.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:241)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:47)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:103)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.robolectric.res.AttrData cannot be cast to org.robolectric.res.StyleData
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager$StyleResolver.getParent(ShadowAssetManager.java:353)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager$StyleResolver.getAttrValue(ShadowAssetManager.java:336)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.findAttributeValue(ShadowResources.java:259)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.attrsToTypedArray(ShadowResources.java:188)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.access$000(ShadowResources.java:51)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources$ShadowTheme.obtainStyledAttributes(ShadowResources.java:460)
at android.content.res.Resources$Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources.java)
at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:374)
at android.view.View.__constructor__(View.java:3297)
at org.fest.reflect.method.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:112)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowView.__constructor__(ShadowView.java:68)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3295)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:253)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:246)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:242)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
at org.robolectric.shadows.RoboLayoutInflater.onCreateView(RoboLayoutInflater.java:38)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at net.frontlinesms.android.ui.view.ActionBar.<init>(ActionBar.java:65)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at org.robolectric.tester.android.view.RoboWindow.setContentView(RoboWindow.java:82)
[truncated, hit stack overflow character limit...]
```

Comment: got the same issue, how did you solve this?

Comment: Hi @VinceV. sorry I didn't find a solution.  I shelved this work and haven't yet come back to it.  Please let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: I did the same thing. Had started with full courage to use tests in android. But gave up.

Answer (score 8):

I finally found the right place to put it. First, the structure of my application is shown as below:

my application is under

```
app/src/main/
```

my test application is under

```
app/src/test/
```

You should name the property file as **robolectric.properties** and put it under

```
src/test/resources/
```

The content of **robolectric.properties** is

```
manifest: src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
```

Then, the test program can finally locate the property file!

Comment: the robolectric.properties was under app/src/test/resources or just src/test/resources?

Comment: app/src/test/resources

Comment: I tried but it didn't work with Robolectric **3.0**.

Answer (score 4):

The `src/test/resources` path as mentioned on the Robolectric blog seems to work for the `org.robolectric.Config.properties` file with the test plugin and Robolectric SNAPSHOTS.
The `RobolectricGradleTestRunner` is no longer required.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the [robolectric gradle plugin](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin) and I faced (or am still facing ;) serious problems with junit testing in AS.

However, once thing that I just found out is the location of the `org.robolectric.Config.properties`. I too tried many places in the source project, but AS only started picking it up after I put it into `build/test-classes`.

You can have a look at my gradle build script at: [Debug gradle-based unit tests with IntelliJ / AndroidStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25468809/debug-gradle-based-unit-tests-with-intellij-androidstudio)

Other steps necessary to get it unit tests running in AS:

1. Reorder the `<orderEntry type="jdk" ... />` to the end of the list in your `<app>.iml` file (this is to prevent the *Stub!!* exceptions, see: https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle) - this step must be repeated, each time you sync with gradle.
2. Add the compiled test files folder to your `<app>.iml` file. Add `<output-test url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/test-classes" />` directly after `<output url=... />` (see: [Android Studio + Robolectric + Gradle Class Not Found Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826252/android-studio-robolectric-gradle-class-not-found-exception) )
3. Compile you app with gradle: `gradlew app:clean app:testDebug` or something like that. I noticed that AS does compile only the source files, but somehow does not compile the test classes, at least not anywhere into the `/build` folder. Gradle on the other hand properly compiles your test classes to `/build/test-classes` and with the configuration in step 2) AS will also pick them up, once compiled. Of course this step has to be repeated, each time you modify your test classes.
   (Note: I also found another solution from Eugen, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24140796/1406325 - i haven't tried that one yet, but it seems doing so does not require the extra step to compile with gradle)
4. Put your `org.robolectric.Config.properties` into `/build/test-classes` (since with step 2) AS will pick it up now.
5. If you also have references to other libraries, you might be in a need of a `project.properties` file (that is if you are facing `Resources$NotFoundException` problems when running your tests). Again, where to put this file? It goes into `<app>/src/main` (See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robolectric/gjpwqRICT5U)

   ```
   android.library.reference.1=../../../library/src/main
   ```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Be careful to put and keep something in build folder. First clean will delete it

Comment: Very true, not fun to maintain, huh. This is the first approach I found, but I am still investigating, and I will update this answer, in case i find a simpler solutions... Otherwise there would still be the option to modify the gradle task and have gradle copy the file there each time it compiles the test sources...

Answer (score 1):

I had luck putting `org.robolectric.Config.properties` in `src/test/res`, but not `src/test/resources`.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to override getConfigProperties() in a subclass of RobolectricTestRunner by putting the property file in a folder and specifying the path as follows:

```
@Override
    protected Properties getConfigProperties() {
        FsFile fs = Fs.currentDirectory();
        InputStream resourceAsStream = null;
        try {
            File f = new File(fs.getPath() + <location-to-file-from-root-dir> + <file-name>);
            resourceAsStream = new FileInputStream(f);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            resourceAsStream = null;
        }
        if (resourceAsStream == null) return null;
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(resourceAsStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return properties;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're following this:
https://github.com/square/gradle-android-test-plugin

I think you should modify your `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)` to the `@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)`

Comment: Thanks Eugen.  I'm getting a different error now, something about `Error inflating class net.frontlinesms.android.ui.view.ActionBar` .  I posted all the output under **Update 1** above

Comment: Note that as of Robolectric 3.1.1, RobolectricGradleTestRunner is deprecated and RobolectricTestRunner should be used instead. Source: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/wiki/3.0-to-3.1-Upgrade-Guide