# How to run unit tests with Android Studio

Tags: android, junit, gradle, android-studio, robolectric

I'm using Jake's Android unit tests plugin for gradle: https://github.com/JakeWharton/gradle-android-test-plugin

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
dependencies {
// analytics
compile('com.crittercism:crittercism-android:3.0.11')

// retrofit
compile('com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.2.2')
compile('com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.2.1')

// dagger
compile('com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.1.0')
compile('com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.1.0')

// compatibility
compile('android.compatibility:android-support:v4-r13')
compile('com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar')

// Picasso
compile('com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.1.1')

// Otto
compile('com.squareup:otto:1.3.4')

// Tests
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.2'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.5.1'
testCompile 'org.easytesting:fest-assert-core:2.0M10'
}
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to run all or specific unit test form Android Studio. I'm getting error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/textui/ResultPrinter
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:113)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.textui.ResultPrinter
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
 ... 3 more
```

And this is correct because running command line doesn't include my JUnit dependency:

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -ea -Didea.launcher.port=7533 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/Android Studio.app/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/Android Studio.app/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar:/Users/eugen/Development/SDK/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-18/android.jar:/Users/eugen/Development/SDK/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-18/data/res:/Users/eugen/Development/SDK/android-sdk-macosx/tools/support/annotations.jar:/Users/eugen/Development/Projects/eBuddy/xms/android/xms3-android/build/classes/alpha/debug:/Users/eugen/.gradle/caches/artifacts-26/filestore/com.squareup.retrofit/retrofit/1.2.2/jar/cdf7b60568092fbcc7a254371c345e92f733c03c/retrofit-1.2.2.jar:/Users/eugen/.gradle/caches/artifacts-26/filestore/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.2.4/jar/a60a5e993c98c864010053cb901b7eab25306568/gson-2.2.4.jar:/Users/eugen/.gradle/caches/artifacts-26/filestore/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp/1.2.1/jar/c3562574496bb4d452d6fc45b817577e98d08afe/okhttp-1.2.1.jar:/Users/eugen/.gradle/caches/artifacts-26/filestore/com.squareup/javawriter/2.1.1/jar/67ff45d9ae02e583d0f9b3432a5ebbe05c30c966/javawriter-2.1.1.jar:/Users/eugen/.gradle/caches/artifacts-26/filestore/com.squareup.dagger/dagger/1.1.0/jar/49f2061c938987c8e56679a731d74fd8448d8742/dagger-1.1.0.jar:/Users/eugen/.gradle/caches/artifacts-26/filestore/com.squareup.picasso/picasso/2.1.1/jar/ab19bfb23f641f189b6dca9a4d393f8dc291103a/picasso-2.1.1.jar:/Users/eugen/.gradle/caches/artifacts-26/filestore/com.squareup/otto/1.3.4/jar/4d72fb811c7b3c0e7f412112020d4430f044e510/otto-1.3.4.jar:/Users/eugen/.gradle/caches/artifacts-26/filestore/com.squareup.dagger/dagger-compiler/1.1.0/jar/ddb38c2be31deeb7a001177f7c358665e350d646/dagger-compiler-1.1.0.jar:/Users/eugen/.gradle/caches/artifacts-26/filestore/javax.inject/javax.inject/1/jar/6975da39a7040257bd51d21a231b76c915872d38/javax.inject-1.jar:/Users/eugen/Development/Projects/eBuddy/xms/android/xms3-android/build/exploded-bundles/ComActionbarsherlockActionbarsherlock440.aar/res:/Users/eugen/Development/Projects/eBuddy/xms/android/xms3-android/build/exploded-bundles/ComActionbarsherlockActionbarsherlock440.aar/classes.jar:/Users/eugen/.gradle/caches/artifacts-26/filestore/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp-protocols/1.2.1/jar/ec2beaefef3bd4f680c17fad8e72e66f2a006f1/okhttp-protocols-1.2.1.jar:/Users/eugen/.gradle/caches/artifacts-26/filestore/com.crittercism/crittercism-android/3.0.11/jar/e30c21ae491d780622ecaee2752969be98140c3/crittercism-android-3.0.11.jar:/Users/eugen/.gradle/caches/artifacts-26/filestore/android.compatibility/android-support/v4-r13/jar/bd6479f5dd592790607e0504e66e0f31c2b4d308/android-support-v4-r13.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 @/private/var/folders/wq/knhztnf105v2_p1t580tj8h80000gp/T/idea_junit701450667388095664.tmp @w@/private/var/folders/wq/knhztnf105v2_p1t580tj8h80000gp/T/idea_working_dirs_junit4927192380605663413.tmp -socket63849
```

I wonder if anyone was able to run unit tests in Android Studio? And if it is possible how make it?

Comment: If youre still looking, try this post http://www.element84.com/easy-testing-with-android-studio.html

Comment: thank you for sharing but I'm looking for the way how to run tests inside studio. Especially I need ability to run one specific test during TDD session.

Comment: as well if you use Jake Wharton's android test plugin for gradle you have specify much less in build.gradle and rung all tests with `gradle check`

Comment: check my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/20329044/561323

Comment: See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing

Comment: @Leco that one is about instrumental tests that are terribly slow. I'm interested in unit test with Robolectric

Comment: Have you tried using the supplied JUnit 3 instead of trying to include JUnit 4?

Comment: You can not use junit 3 with robolectric

Comment: This is just so infuriating in Android Studio :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update for AS 1.1+, android gradle plugin 1.1+**

Finally it is possible without many tricks. Here is example of project that shows how to setup `Robolectric` test in `Android Studio v1.1+` and `android gradle plugin v1.1+`:
https://github.com/nenick/AndroidStudioAndRobolectric

You can find also there possible issue and workarounds. Yes, `Robolectric` is complex and not officially supported by Google so it still has some issues. But most of the time it works and brings huge value to your project.

I would also encourage you to start using `Robolectric v3+`. It is almost released and stable enough.

**Old answer for AS 0.x and 1.0x and android gradle plugin version below 1.1**

I managed to make it with help of friends.

So basically you need to make next changes to run Robolectric unit tests in Android Studio:

1. Copy your classpath for test (you can find it as first line in "Run" log)
2. Open run configuration for your unit tests
3. Change working dir to folder where AndroidManifest.xml is present
4. Add VM Option `-classpath "<path_to_project_folder>/build/test-classes:<path_to_gradle_cache>/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.11/4e031bb61df09069aeb2bffb4019e7a5034a4ee0/junit-4.11.jar:<your old classpath>"`

As for me the start of new classpath looks like this:

```
/Users/emartynov/Development/Projects/work/android.project/build/test-classes:/Users/emartynov/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.11/4e031bb61df09069aeb2bffb4019e7a5034a4ee0/junit-4.11.jar
```

Problems:

1. You can run test only for debug variant
2. Every new test run configuration requires such manual changes. But this is simply copy/paste of two edit fields

I have Android Studio 0.6 version. Here is again part of my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://github.com/rockerhieu/mvn-repo/raw/master/' }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.3'
  //  classpath 'org.robolectric.gradle:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.10.1'
    classpath 'org.robolectric.gradle:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.10.1-SNAPSHOT'
    classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.10.+'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'android-test'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 19
  buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
  }

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.9.0"
  }

  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
  }

  sourceSets {
    androidTest.setRoot( 'src/test' )
  }
}

dependencies {
  // butter knife
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.0.0'
  // dagger
  compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1'

  // apt
  apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.+'

  // AS tests
  androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'
  androidTestCompile( 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3' ) {
    exclude group: 'commons-logging'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
  }
  androidTestCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.+'
  androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.+'
  androidTestCompile 'org.easytesting:fest-assert-core:2.0M10'
  androidTestCompile( 'org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:1.2.+' ) {
    exclude group: 'org.json'
  }

  // tests
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'
  testCompile( 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3' ) {
    exclude group: 'commons-logging'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
  }
  testCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.+'
  testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.+'
  testCompile 'org.easytesting:fest-assert-core:2.0M10'
  testCompile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.+'
  testCompile( 'org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:1.2.+' ) {
    exclude group: 'org.json'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 30):

just add folder named instrumentTest under /src 
it should have /java inside like this

[image]

then extend the class ActivityTestCase (or any other android unit-test-class), such as

```
package com.example.app.test;

import android.test.ActivityTestCase;

import junit.framework.Assert;


public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityTestCase {


public void testHappy(){
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
}

}
```

right click on green java directory and select run all tests 
and you should get this:

[image]

good luck

Comment: I moved my answer here (I wanted to put the answer here in the first place), this is what you have to do to run unit-tests in android studio. At least this is what I understand you want to do, did I understand your question wrong?

Comment: I was asking for Robolectric unit test not instrumental

Comment: sorry, I have not noticed that - I taught it was in different question, do you want me to remove the answer?

Comment: you can keep it. So maybe some people will find it useful

Comment: it seem that on Android Studio 0.5.7, "instrumentTest" should be renamed to "androidTest"

Comment: @zebra  Why do you put /instrumentTest under /src?  It should be at the same top-level as /src, not under it...

Comment: this is where android studio is expecting it to be, I just checked it and its working exactly like this

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem and found a solution - include the classes.jar from the exploded bundle (.aar) in the build folder. I don't think will help with finding resources in .aar dependencies though.

```
testCompile fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/exploded-bundles", include: "**/classes.jar")
```

**Edit:** Since Android Gradle build tools **0.9.0** the dependency has changed to:

```
androidTestCompile fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/exploded-aar", include: "**/classes.jar")
```

**Edit 2:** Since Android Gradle build tools **0.10.0** the dependency has changed to:

```
androidTestCompile fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/../../build/exploded-aar", include: "**/classes.jar")
```

*Note: the relative path may be different depending on your project structure.*

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't help to run Robolectric unit tests

Comment: tried this, still gettin `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/textui/ResultPrinter` -- it seems to be running my system JDK `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java` could that be it?

Comment: @AlexChaffee with gradle build tools 0.10.0 the location of exploded aars changed again (see updated answer) - that might be your problem.

Comment: Regarding the "NoClassDefFoundError: I followed the instructions here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826252/android-studio-robolectric-gradle-class-not-found-exception). Adding the `<output-test ...` instruction to my `.iml` file helped to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

For posterity **Android Studio 2.0+** supports running Unit tests without plugins.

[image: JUnit configuration in Android Studio 2.0+]

This screen can be accessed through menu Run > Edit Configurations...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with AS 1.2.2.

I followed the steps [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support#TOC-Setting-up-Android-Studio).  Basically:

- Opened the "Build Variants" tool window (see image on the link) and changed the "Test Artifact" drop-down to "Unit tests".
- Create a directory for your testing source code, i.e. `src/test/java`, and move your test to the respective package there.
- Make sure the following sections of your `build.gradle` file contain these:

  ```
  dependencies { 
      testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  }

  android {
      sourceSets {
          test {
              resources {
                  srcDir "test"
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Voila!  Right-click your test case and select the JUnit flavor.

BTW, it seems to toggle the visibility of the JUnit/Android tests when you change the "Build Variants" tool, so my guess is you can either test as JUnit or Android but not both at same time.

Comment: Thanks for answering! the question is not relevant anymore :) BTW Android Studio 1.3 stable is out and 1.4 is in the preview now (if you're not afraid)