# Is there a way to execute a single Robolectric 2.3 test (using Gradle)?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric

I'm using Robolectric 2.3 and execute my unit tests with

```
./gradlew testDebug
```

Is there a way to execute a single test or a single test class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm running them in Android Studio and from there you can execute one test, one test case, all tests in the package:
[How to run unit tests with Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891564/how-to-run-unit-tests-with-android-studio/24140796#24140796)

About command line you can take a look on this plugin:
https://github.com/JCAndKSolutions/android-unit-test

Comment: android-unit-test is no more supported it has been deprecated @Eugen Martynov