# Android Studio 1.1, simple junit test setup

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-studio

I have read around, there are a number of extensive answers (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17844957/running-simple-junit-tests-on-android-studio-intellij-when-using-a-gradle-base?rq=1)) but the Android world evolves so fast that they seem to be a bit outdated and the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html) still refers to Eclipse with ADT.

I am running AS 1.1 and I am trying to setup simple junit tests to run on the emulator, without Robolectric. If I don't include junit in my `build.gradle`, it can't find `@After`, `@Before` and `@Test` and I get `package org.junit does not exist`. Upon adding

```
// unit tests
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
```

the error becomes

```
Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK
[...]/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-test-unaligned.apk
Path in archive: LICENSE.txt
Origin 1: [...]/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
Origin 2: [...]/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.11/4e031bb61df09069aeb2bffb4019e7a5034a4ee0/junit-4.11.jar
You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:
android {
  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
  }
}
```

Following the console suggestion of excluding LICENSE.txt, it then works but it feels like a hack. So I'm wondering, am I maybe missing something? Thanks.

Comment: That's the way we have been doing it in our project and it seems to be the expected way.

Comment: Exclude the LICENSE.txt is a normal practice :) (and also the META-INF/LICENSE.txt and the META-INF/NOTICE.txt)

Comment: Having the same issue, where are your tests located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Studio unit testing support comes in 1.1 Beta 4 ([release announcement](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio11betaavailable)) with Gradle plugin version `1.1.0-rc1`.
More info in [official document](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support).

However it is experimental feature for now. E.g. it [breaks](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=135513) `installDebug` gradle task.

For using JUnit in instrumentation tests there is [good guide](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSetupInstructions) for Espresso library and [another](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/AndroidJUnitRunnerUserGuide) covering new AndroidJUnitRunner.

Answer (score 1):

If it's any use I set up a boiler plate project allowing the use of Unit tests and Espresso tests by the use of switching build variants. You won't need the use of any third party plugins with this.

https://github.com/hitherejoe/Android-Boilerplate

Comment: no problem! I'll be updating it over the next few days with the new version of robolectric etc - enjoy!