# Java Version Error while installing Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, macos, bash, tomcat, terminal

I know this question was asked so many times but I never found an answer that relates to my question.
I am trying to install Apache Tomcat server on my MacBook Pro. All answers were answered for Windows and Eclipse. I want to install and configure the server using Terminal. So the problem is happening at the last step of the installation. I am getting the below error while installing the server.
I know this is a problem is about Java version at run time, but I can't fix it.
Note: I have already updated my Java version to the latest one.
Please help.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
> org/apache/catalina/startup/Bootstrap : Unsupported major.minor
> version 51.0
>
> ```
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
>     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
> ```

Comment: What version of tomcat you are trying to install and what version of java is installed?

Comment: So what is your Java and your OS version? Updating Java (or downgrading Tomcat) is probably the only way to go.

Comment: The version is Tomcat 8 and the OS version is 10.7.5

Comment: java version "1.6.0_51"

Comment: It actually shows Java 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say you've got the latest version, but then you also say you're using Java 1.6_051. That is *not* the latest version of Java.

You need Java 7 - see [this page](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml) for how to install Java 7 on Mac OSX.

If you can't install Java 7 on your machine for some reason, you'll need to use a different version of Tomcat. Tomcat 8 *requires* Java 7, as shown on the ["which version" Tomcat page](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html). You might also wish to consider using an older version of Tomcat anyway, given that Tomcat 8.0 is still only at RC-1 level - I would typically stick with a stable version unless you're willing to take on the pain of pre-releases.

Comment: I know it shows Java 7 when I view it in the System Preferences. But when I view it in terminal using java -version is shows the mentioned version

Comment: @Jack: Well that sounds like you need to change your path to pick up Java 7 from the terminal.

Comment: That's the problem is what I can't figure our, Jon. Please advise how can I do so. Thanks

Comment: please see this reference  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588390/where-is-java-home-on-osx-lion-10-7-or-mountain-lion-10-8

Comment: Awesome Jon. I just installed Apache Tomecat version 7 and it worked!! thanks!

Answer (score -1):

For Tomcat 8 Any installed Java 7 or later JRE (32-bit or 64-bit) may be used.

Please read the requirements

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/setup.html

Comment: I actually did and I mentioned that I did the update for the latest version for Java. Please read what I have said before answering questions. Thanks