# Android Studio - Unable to Run Project: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I'm having an issue building my project in Android Studio, it was working fine a couple of weeks back, but when I tried to run the project today it fails. Here's the error message I get:

> org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not execute build
>   using Gradle distribution
>   'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.7-bin.zip'.: Could
>   not execute build using Gradle distribution
>   'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.7-bin.zip'.

A tried a couple of things:

- Re-download the bin.zip file again and replace it in the appropriate folder
- I also tried changing from classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+' to just classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.7', same result.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I ended up uninstalling Android Studio Completely after all. After doing so, I noticed that new projects were now on Gradle 0.6.+, which in turn utilizes gradle-1.8-bin.zip. I updated my build.gradle to the new settings and it finally compiled again.

Comment: Thanks, Your edit helped solved it - it cost me an hour though. Why is Google incapable of delivering updates without breaking projects?

Answer (score 0):

This is marked as known issue in the [developer android](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#Troubleshooting) page

Also in my case need to update the JAVA_HOME path, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588390/where-is-java-home-on-osx-lion-10-7-mountain-lion-10-8-or-mavericks-10-9) could help you

Also I had to reconfigure the SDK path and downloading the repository support as mentioned in the Troubleshooting section.

Comment: While I do appreciate your help, the link provided for troubleshooting references two different errors, not even similar to this one. As far as the JAVA_HOME, the guide provided is for Mac OSX, and I doubt it has to do with that. As for the support repository, I was already using it :)

Answer (score 0):

At the end none of the solutions worked for me, not even the ones from my previous reponse. I resolved the issue creating a project again using the existing sources ("Import Project" option), seems like new version of android studio makes imposible to use old structure of the project, so that made the trick, basically start over a new project structure using all the existing source.

I hope it helps. This was the one that worked for me.