# Failed to install jdk 1.7 on mac

Tags: java, macos, java-7

I'm trying to install JDK 1.7 update 21 on Mac OSX 10.7 . 
I downloaded the installer from oracle site (as dmg file). ran the installer which completed successfully. 
Now I can't find the java SDK anywhere on the file system. 
The output of `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` is :

```
  ***/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home***
```

which is the previous version installed. 
also running java -version executes the same old version.

```
***Java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)***
```

In the java control panel I do see that the JRE has updated to Java 1.7 for the browser but there aren't any details regarding the JDK there.

Where can I find the new `JDK` on the file system and how do I set it as default ?
Is there any log file for the installation that I can use to debug ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is JAVA\_HOME on OSX Lion (10.7) , Mountain Lion (10.8) or Mavericks (10.9)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588390/where-is-java-home-on-osx-lion-10-7-mountain-lion-10-8-or-mavericks-10-9)

Comment: Installing jdk 1.7 update 17 works fine, there is something wrong with later releases

Comment: I've got jdk update 40 installed locally without any problems. I'm running Mavericks 10.9 with Apple JDK 1.6.0 build 37 and Oracle JDK 1.7.0 build 40. My `.bashrc` contains `export JAVA_HOME=``/usr/libexec/java_home`` ` and I set `java_home` to default to Java 1.7.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your shell startup script (.bash_profile off of ~ if you are using bash):

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.7*'`
```

The changeover from Apple providing the JDK to Oracle has been a complete disaster.