# Setting Java home enviroment variable in OSX Mavericks

Tags: java, macos, environment-variables, osx-mavericks

I am having issues with my Java path.

I have installed the latest version of Java 1.7.0_51. When I open the Java control panel it tells me **"Your system has the recommended version of Java."**

[image: Java Control Panel]

However when I go to terminal and type `java -version` I get

```
java version "1.6.0_32"
```

So after searching around I came across this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588390/where-is-java-home-on-osx-lion-10-7-mountain-lion-10-8-or-mavericks-10-9) which tells me that my Java home environment variable needs to be set.

I then opened the bash_profile file and added the below line to the top of the file, above my Python path info.

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7.0_51`


# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

**NOTE:** I have tried this with both `-v 1.7.0_51` and `-v 1.7`

I save the file and recheck in terminal but it is still showing

```
java version "1.6.0_32"
```

when I restart Terminal I do however see

```
Last login: Wed Feb 19 23:32:19 on ttys000
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.7".
localhost:/ user$
```

Note: **Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.7".**

So it is trying to look for my 1.7, but just not finding it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have that previous version installed? If you do maybe uninstall it?

Comment: This should not be necessary and I may need Java 6 in the near future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think this must be specific to me. As above the Java control panel was saying that java 7 was installed. Also when i tried

```
/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
```

I would get

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
```

But no mater what way I installed the [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) it would not work. It just didn't seem to appear anywhere on my machine. I still don't know why, but uninstalling (by simply deleting the 1.6 folder) the existing Java 6 from my machine and once again installing Java 7 JDK eventually fixed it.

Please give the up-votes to @diaz994 above.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether there is an old version existed in the path

```
echo $PATH
```

Then set the java 1.7 bin directory.

```
export PATH=/usr/libexec/java_1.7_home/bin:$PATH
```

Then try to type in "java -version" in terminal to check the version

Comment: When I type echo $PATH I see my python path info. e.g. "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:" The second instruction (copy-pasted exactly) has no effect when I check the version. I also restarted Terminal to see if it would work.

Comment: You can't just copy it. It's an example. You have to use your own JDK bin directory "export PATH=/YOUR_JDK_PATH/bin:$PATH"

Comment: I think I tried that this morning, afterwards. I'll check again when I'm back at the computer tomorrow, thanks again