# Incompatible JVM error message with 64 bit Eclipse on MacBook Pro

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, osx-mavericks

I keep getting the following message when I try to open Eclipse Juno on my Macbook Pro:

> **Incompatible JVM** Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version:
>   1.7 or greater is required.

Every answer to this question suggests to download and install a 64-bit version of Eclipse. But I already have the 64 bit version and so that's not the solution I'm expecting.
This is the name of the file that I downloaded from eclipse site:

**eclipse-standard-luna-R-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz**

You can see that it is the 64 bit version only. Correct me if I'm wrong.

java -version command returns this:

> java version "1.6.0_65"

javac -version command returns this:

> javac 1.6.0_65

But the Java control panel shows the following message:

```
Your system has the recommended version of Java.
Java 7 Update 67
```

So I have both version 6 and 7 on my machine. How do I force eclipse to use that version 7?

Comment: set the "JAVA_HOME" avriable to the version 7 path.

Comment: Use [`/usr/libexec/java_home`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6588390/230513) to establish `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: @Jens that does not work with Eclipse.

Comment: Could you try reinstalling the latest version of Java?

Comment: Solved the issue. I'm guessing the problem was with the JDK in my machine. I installed the latest Oracle 64 bit JDK and everything started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most probable problem is the version of your eclipse. If you install the 32-bit version, that should work. Java Runtime is 32-bit, so 64-bit eclipse doesn't work with it!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set Java 7 in path and since you have both Java 6 & 7 installed, in order to avoid conflict, set it first thing in the Path variable before everything else.

Something like:

> PATH=Path_to_java_7;everything else here