# Mac OS Yosemite and java classpaths

Tags: java, macos, osx-yosemite

For school we need to add a library for Java development. These are the steps that we need to follow:

1. `$ cd ~`
2. `nano ~/.profile`
3. Add: `export CLASSPATH=.:~/Library/javautils/*:$CLASSPATH`
4. Save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Quit nano with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>
6. Quit and reopen Terminal

But when I try `echo $CLASSPATH` it doesn't return anything. On Mavericks it didn't seem to be a problem. So it's Yosemite's fault. Anybody have any I idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: I'd get rid of * not that this helps with your problem.

Comment: @Goibniu the star is significant - `foo/*` in a classpath means "all the `.jar` files in the directory `foo`", whereas just `foo` means the directory itself.

Comment: Can you tell us what happens when you write `shopt nullglob` in your terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [Where is JAVA_HOME on OSX Sierra (10.12), El Captain (10.11), Yosemite (10.10), Mavericks (10.9), Mountain Lion (10.8) or OSX Lion (10.7)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588390/where-is-java-home-on-osx-yosemite-10-10-mavericks-10-9-mountain-lion-10)

Java 6 is not compatible with Yosemite, if you have Java6 you should update to a newer version.

Comment: Yes, but Just with version that you can download from apple site: JavaForOSX2014-001.dmg