# No CurrentJDK directory

Tags: xcode, bash, java-7, java-home, jdk1.7

I am on OS X Yosemite 10.10.3

I am running XCODE and receive the error

`Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/bin/java`

I have looked at [Where is JAVA_HOME on OSX Sierra (10.12), El Captain (10.11), Yosemite (10.10), Mavericks (10.9), Mountain Lion (10.8) or OSX Lion (10.7)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588390/where-is-java-home-on-osx-yosemite-10-10-mavericks-10-9-mountain-lion-10) 
and tried all of the suggestions for the JAVA_HOME variable.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling java and the jdk from Oracle

`java -version` gives me

java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

I have made sure that in all the suggestions I replaced the version # with my correct version #.

Everyone that has made a response seems to have a `CurrentJDK` within /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/.

I only have `A` and `Current`

I am wondering if this is part of the reason I am getting the error, and how would I fix that?

Comment: Well, what's in the `Current` directory?

Comment: @Luke `Commands  JavaPluginCocoa.bundle _CodeSignature
Frameworks  JavaVM
Headers   Resources`

Comment: Have you tried searching for java or javaw (the latter will probably give fewer results and narrow down the search) in JavaVM.framework? I'm not sure about the extension, I don't get around Macs well, but it'll report everything and you can see what you need. Then you just need to find the right file and see in which directory it is. Unless, of course, by then someone comes up with a more precise answer.

Comment: @Luke There is a java inside of `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin`

I have my current attempt of home as `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)`

which points to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java_home`

Comment: That looks reasonable, could you try setting it as JAVA_HOME? Just guessing though, try with a few apps afterwards

Comment: @Luke Changing it to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin`

or

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`

Does not fix the error =/

Comment: Right, glad you find the solution anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/`

`sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents CurrentJDK`

Running these 2 lines fixed my issue, and added a CurrentJDK to the Versions directory.

Comment: ln: CurrentJDK: Read-only file system