# Program can't find any version of Java, even though I know it's installed

Tags: java, macos, osx-yosemite

I'm attempting to download and use a data visualization program from the internet, and I keep running into an error regarding the version of Java that I'm using. When I downloaded it, it said something along the lines of "This program requires Legacy Java Runtime 6 to open", along with a link where I could download the legacy version of Java from the Mac OS. I downloaded it, and when I attempted to open the program again, it said:

"ERROR launching 'NOAA Weather and Climate Toolkit 3.7.7'

No suitable Java version found on your system!
This program requires Java 1.7+
Make sure you install the required Java version."

So, I went to the Java website and downloaded Java 1.8, yet I keep getting the same error as above when I attempt to open the program. I've checked through the Java website and through the settings box on my computer, and they both show that Java 1.8 is installed. So, why can't this program find Java and/or what can I do to fix it?

Comment: if you open the terminal and run the command "java -version" or "javac -version", what is the output?

Comment: Here is the output from the command line: "javac version "1.6.0_65"". However, when I go to System Preferences > Java > Java Control Panel > About, it says "Version 8 Update 51, 1.8.0_51". I'm not sure what could be causing the discrepancy.

Comment: You need to update your JAVA_HOME environment variable and point to java 8. This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588390/where-is-java-home-on-osx-yosemite-10-10-mavericks-10-9-mountain-lion-10

Comment: That worked. Also, a note to anyone else who happens to stumble across this, make sure you install the Java Development Kit (JDK) instead of just the Java Runtime Environment (JRE). I tried the suggestion in @Juan's link with just the JRE, and it said "Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8"". However, when I downloaded the JDK instead, it worked fine.