# MacOS Big Sur 11.1 can't launch eclipse installer

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, macos-big-sur

I updated my MacOS to Big Sur 11.1 and I tried to download Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, and when I try to run the Eclipse Installer, it keep spinning at the Mac dock and nothing happens at all. The launcher doesn't move forward with the process like this:

[image]

I have Java installed and I checked the version like this :

```
$ /usr/bin/java -version 
java version "15.0.2" 2021-01-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.2+7-27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517507/how-to-set-java-home-environment-variable-on-macos) to setup Java directory home

Then, I updated the JAVA_HOME using the below commands:

```
$ vi ~/.bash_profile
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Then, in a new terminal window and test the variable is setup like this:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Hom
```

And I still have issues to run Eclipse Installer, so I found these links ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60765789/eclipse-installation-on-macos) , [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62647625/not-able-to-run-eclipse-on-macos-big-sur)) explaining how I should edit the eclipse.ini file and  info.plist file in the Contents folder in Eclipse.app as it is shown in the pictures:

[image]

This is the line in eclipse.ini:

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/Java
```

[image]

In the info.plist, I added this under Eclipse, array as it shown:

```
<key>Eclipse</key>

    <array>
        <string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/Java</string>
```

[image]

And still the Eclipse installer doesn't work, I contacted apple support and they said  that the problem is need to be take care of from the Eclipse side and they can't do anything about it ..

Does anyone has any idea how  to avoid this problem or fix the issue I have.. I tried multiple times to remove java and install it again and I still facing the same problem .

Also I tired this command using Homebrew but I keep getting this error Message you see in the picture:

```
brew cask install eclipse-java
```

[image]

I'm really in need for help, and I spent more than 10 days to figure out what the issue is and I'm very frustrated , and I need to install this Eclipse in particular for school.

Thank you!

Comment: The installer download now includes a JRE with which to run it. You should not be changing that setup. If you do, only one line should follow the -vm line in the .ini file. And /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/Java is likely incorrect--the "java" binary is usually named using all lower case.
When you were trying to run it originally, were you running it directly out of the disk image, or after copying it onto your local drive? And you can always just download the package directly from the "Download Packages" link, https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/ .

Comment: The path for 15.0.2 is `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java` - lower case `java` at the end.

Comment: @nitind  Thank you so much for explaining, I did changed "Java" into lower case "java" and I still have the same issue. When I run the Eclipse.dmg it opens a window and I dragged eclipse icon into the applications folder and I run it from there..  I'm still not able to run Eclipse and I'm hoping to find a solution for my problem please

Comment: @greg-449  Thanks! I deleted Eclipse and downloaded it again and I updated the info file with the directory  :<string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>.  But still doesn't work.. This is so frustrating

Comment: With the current Eclipse 2020-12 and Java 15.0.2 there should be no need to change anything, it should just run. As suggested in the first comment you could try one of the Eclipse packages which doesn't use the installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, and what I did is I shutdown my Mac and then I pressed on Option + Control + Shift buttons for 7 seconds, and I kept pressing on these 3 buttons and I pressed on the power button with them for another 10 seconds.
After this the mac will start running.
Go again and shutdown the system again and repeat the same thing with the Option +Control + Shift for 7 seconds, and the power button again with them for another 10 seconds.
Then I run the Eclipse and it worked !!
I got the instructions from Apple support and I hope if someone faced the same issue , can benefit from my post!

Thank you everyone for trying to help .