# How to set java --version corresponding to JAVA_HOME on Mac OS 12.6

Tags: java, macos, java-8, java-17

I run Java on MacOS Monterey(12.6) and have two versions of JDKs installed:

```
user@Users-iMac ~ % ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
jdk-17.0.2.jdk  openjdk-8.jdk
```

I want to work with Java 17. My concern is that the command `java -version` generates the info that I do NOT want:

```
user@Users-iMac ~ % java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_362"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_362-bre_2023_01_22_03_30-b00)
```

whereas the command `echo $JAVA_HOME` displays the correct version that I DO want

```
user@Users-iMac ~ % echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

How can I make `java -version make point to Java 17 instead of Java 8?

Thanks

Singham

Comment: I'm not too familiar with macs, but didn't they have a tool named `sdkman` that solves this problem?

Comment: What does your PATH look like. If you have JAVA_HOME pointing at a correct JDK it should work, but if you have added something to your path then it might find a different version of java first. What is the output of `which java`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set JAVA\_HOME environment variable on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517507/how-to-set-java-home-environment-variable-on-macos)

Comment: The `JAVA_HOME` is something used by tools using Java to locate the JDK; it is not something that is actually used by Java itself, nor by your OS (unless you yourself added `$JAVAHOME$/bin` to the `PATH`).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel OSX will let you select java's using java home. It will always refer to a /system/path/java but different java's will run.

Comment: @matt As far as I'm aware, that doesn't use `JAVA_HOME`, but some configuration tool (which IIRC changes a symlink), but I have been using sdkman on my work Mac for so long, I can't remember to alternative any more, and I'm using Windows at home.

Comment: Maybe this is a better answer, it will tell you what JDK's you have available ie correctly installed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24657630/2067492

Comment: @MarkRotteveel When I had a mac, I didn't use JAVA_HOME for things beyond maven. Then I followed a question on here, and learned that JAVA_HOME can change the default jdk.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround is settting up my environment by editing `.bash_profile` file:

```bash
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 17`
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

It is better to automate using an alias or an executable which comes handy for example when you have to set-up a different Maven version also for the particular Java:

```bash
cp ~/.bash-profile-java-11 ~/.bash-profile
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't play with `PATH` in this case, only with `JAVA_HOME`.
The commands relative to java in `/usr/bin/` are front-ends which use the `JAVA_HOME` variable to locate the correct binaries.

But if you mix `JAVA_HOME=<java17>` with a `PATH=<java8>:...` then obviously `java` command from java8 will be executed.

At least, put `/usr/bin` in front of `<java8>` in your `PATH`. Best is to never have a reference to a java installation in `PATH`.

As a macOS user, I **never** play with `PATH` when I use java, only `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Add `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 17)` to your `~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same usecase where I have to switch to different java version for different projects

This is what I use to switch between different java versions

```
alias j8='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_8_HOME'
alias j19='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_19_HOME'
alias j11='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_11_HOME'
```

you can define JAVA_x_HOME with specific path

e.g. JAVA_8_HOME --> `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: Hehe I have exactly the same - but on Linux

Comment: OP already has set JAVA_HOME, but it isn't using the correct jdk. So this answer doesn't address the issue.

Comment: Yes I was about to say that the alias *must* finish with `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score -1):

Just to get rid of some of the confusion about aliases and to show how `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` interconnect, the following alias approach is what I use. This should be defined where it will be sourced automatically, which for me is ~/.bash_aliases, but might be something different for MacOS

```
alias j8='export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/bellsoft-java8-full-amd64;export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH'
```

Comment: OSX uses (or at least used to) JAVA_HOME to delegate which java gets run. It has a stub in /usr/bin/java (or something similar) which you update JAVA_HOME correctly that stub will start the correct java. You don't need to change the PATH at all. Although if you have already changed the path, then JAVA_HOME won't change the version of java being run.