# Can't switch Java version in mac

Tags: java, java-8, java-11

I did my due diligence and researched. I followed the following steps:

1. `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`

result was:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    11.0.13 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 11.0.13" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.13.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_372 (x86_64) "Homebrew" - "OpenJDK 8" /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@8/1.8.0+372/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
```

2. export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_372`
3. echo $JAVA_HOME

result was:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@8/1.8.0+372/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
```

4. But when I do java -version, the following result shows up:

   java version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19 LTS
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.13+10-LTS-370)
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.13+10-LTS-370, mixed mode)

Result shows default java is still Java 11. I want to switch it to use Java 1.8

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set java --version corresponding to JAVA\_HOME on Mac OS 12.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76512739/how-to-set-java-version-corresponding-to-java-home-on-mac-os-12-6)

Answer (score 2):

I use https://sdkman.io/ to manage different java versions on my mac(M1).

I've installed several java versions using sdkman and it is easy to switch in between those versions using sdkman with one command.

Answer (score 0):

I use
jenv
to switch between different java versions on mac.

```
>brew info jenv
==> jenv: stable 0.5.6 (bottled), HEAD
Manage your Java environment
https://www.jenv.be/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jenv/0.5.6 (86 files, 78KB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2023-02-15 at 07:31:25
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/jenv.rb
License: MIT
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
To activate jenv, add the following to your shell profile e.g. ~/.profile
or ~/.zshrc:
  export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"
  eval "$(jenv init -)"
```

With

```
jenv local 11.0
```

or

```
jenv local 17.0
```

for example,
I can switch do different versions of installed java.