# The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved error on VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

On VS Code, recently when I imported a java project, I got this error

The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I am on a mac operating system, a few days ago Java was working fine but now it is not, how do I fix this?

Comment: Did you search here on Stackoverflow for similar questions, or solutions like [Visual Studio Code - Java - Import Errors and More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45743779/visual-studio-code-java-import-errors-and-more) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my build path suddenly incomplete for my java project in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77092008/why-is-my-build-path-suddenly-incomplete-for-my-java-project-in-visual-studio-co)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77097506/the-project-was-not-built-since-its-build-path-is-incomplete-vscode-error

Comment: did you update anything recently? Your JDK? VS Code? Please give version numbers for all the things. Please also show us what you see in the Language Support for Java channel in the Output Panel