# What's the build path problem in a java project

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

[image: Error Showing in my IDE]

I have been working with Java for one month but haven't encountered this problem until now. I'm unable to find a solution for this issue.

If anyone is able to provide a solution, please specify the reason behind this problem as well.

Comment: Images and screen shots are normally used for imagery and not for text such as error messages, source code, etc. You need to edit your question and replace the screen shot with two sections of text: the source code for the posted question and the error messages generated by the source code. Doing so allows people to try out the source code of the post for themselves and to perform a search on the errors to find additional information. Please edit your posted question to make these two changes.

Comment: calls to mind https://stackoverflow.com/q/77092008/11107541, but that's probably only a superficial relation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try `Ctrl+Shift+P-->>Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace`

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me like you need to also `import java.io.*`.

See this article about Java streams. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-io-input-output-in-java-with-examples/

At the top of your source you need at a minimum:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Comment: This will not solve the error that Hitesh posted. Something is wrong with the configuration of his IDE or with his Java runtime environment. It is not a compile error that is caused because an import statement is missing.