# cannot set JAVA_HOME on macosx

Tags: java, macos, terminal

I am using OS X EL Capitan 10.11.

I set JAVA_Home in `~/.bashrc`

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Seems like nothing worked even I closed and re-opened terminal. It still says

```
+======================================================================+
|      Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and Java could not be found         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I thought it was same like Linux but it looks like it is not. Is there anywhere else I should export JAVA_HOME?

Comment: And are you actually using bash or have you changed your shell? You can check it by running `echo $SHELL` in the terminal.

Comment: @dunni it says `/bin/bash`

Comment: This should help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588390/where-is-java-home-on-osx-yosemite-10-10-mavericks-10-9-mountain-lion-10

Comment: Check your `~/.bash_profile` whether you have `[[ -s ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc` or not

Answer (score 0):

The java executable is referred from the below path:

`/usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java`