# Can't get Derby Database to work with mac

Tags: eclipse, server, derby

I configured the jar file for derby and the json-simple-1.1.1 file but I can't get the Derby to run on eclipse. it says:

> Last login: Thu Nov 24 12:39:49 on ttys000
>   /Users/Adam/Downloads/db-derby-10.13.1.1-bin\ 2/bin/startNetworkServer
>   ; exit; Adams-MacBook-Pro:~ Adam$
>   /Users/Adam/Downloads/db-derby-10.13.1.1-bin\ 2/bin/startNetworkServer
>   ; exit; Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.   We cannot execute
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/bin/java logout
>   Saving session... ...copying shared history... ...saving
>   history...truncating history files... ...completed.
>
> [Process completed]

every time I try to run startNetworkServer.
It's really frustrating I can't find anything online. Derby should work on mac but I don't know what else to do.

Comment: You need to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the location of your Java installation.

Comment: how do I do that? couldn't find a working solution

Comment: Well how are you running this? Is it from a Run Configuration? from Terminal? What Java version do you have installed?

Comment: I'm running it from run configuration and I get "Error: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused" because the server can't be connected without the startNetworkServer that I can't get right. I'm using java 1.8 which works great for android studio and eclipse. but not server

Comment: Before you run startNetworkServer, you'll need to do something like `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/jre`, but of course correct that actual path for the true location of your Java installation on your Mac.

Comment: Try studying http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588390/where-is-java-home-on-osx-yosemite-10-10-mavericks-10-9-mountain-lion-10?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me 3 days to figure it out I hope it could help others as it helped me.
The solution was running the following commands in the terminal:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
```

Path to your Derby folder(Change mine to yours):

```
export DERBY_HOME=/Users/Adam/Documents/DERBY/db-derby-10.13.1.1-bin
```

running the actual file startNetworkServer can't work so you need to run this command:

```
java -jar $DERBY_HOME/lib/derbynet.jar start
```

if everything went well the server should be up and running on port 1527.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to the path to the `Home` directory in your Java installation.

In a Run Configuration you can set the JAVA_HOME environment variable on the 'Environment' tab of the configuration.

For Java 8 JDK installs the path will be something like:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home
```

(you will have to adjust this to match your system).

You will have to create this variable using the 'New...' button as it won't exist by default.

[image: Environment tab]

Comment: where is the JAVA_HOME environment variable? I can't find it anywhere.
I have 2 folders: jdk1.8.0_65.jdk and jdk1.8.0_101.jdk in the JavaVirtualMachines folder

Comment: You have to ADD this as it doesn't currently exist.

Comment: But what do you mean by "JAVA_HOME environment variable"? I am inside the home directory how do I set this variable?

Comment: I already said you can add it in the Run Configuration (see added picture). You could even just edit the `startNetworkServer` script and change the default path there.

Comment: Yes of course it is Eclipse. It is part of the Run > Run Configurations dialog.

Comment: I found and did it was just about to post a comment but it's not related to the  Derby files which are not working because of that error I posted. So something should be done before configuring eclipse. all windows users had no problem running the startNetworkServer.bat file and we mac users had trouble doing the same with the other startNetworkServer file. The error message is posted on my initial question. Thank you for your help any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the post is a bit older, but as I'm dealing with the Derby at school I've also faced the same problem.
I simply opened the db-derby-10.16.11-bin/bin/ij file in vs-code and rewrote the JAVA_HOME path (line 31 in the picture)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtMfg.png)