# Error unable to locate tools.jar on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: java, macos, ant, jar

I got the following error when I installed `ant` and checked its version using `ant -v` command.

```
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar
```

Most of the posts are related to windows and other OS. I couldn't understand that solution to solve my problem. I am using Mac OS Sierra. Help me out with this situation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See [Where is JAVA_HOME on OSX Sierra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588390/where-is-java-home-on-osx-sierra-10-12-el-captain-10-11-yosemite-10-10) for help on setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable so it points to a JDK.

Comment: Thanks chad nouis it helped me  and everthing is working good.