# Setting up JAVA HOME on macOS Catalina

Tags: java, macos-catalina, java-home

I'm just starting out with Java and trying to setup JAVA_HOME on Mac OS Catalina, so the default terminal is zsh instead of bash. Where do I setup JAVA_HOME, in zprofile or in .zshrc ?  Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This question has been addressed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588390/where-is-java-home-on-macos-mojave-10-14-to-lion-10-7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is JAVA\_HOME on macOS Mojave (10.14) to Lion (10.7)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588390/where-is-java-home-on-macos-mojave-10-14-to-lion-10-7)