# Difference between .profile and .bash_profile on Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I am going to set the path for mySQl on my computer (I'm running Snow Leopard) but I see different instructions online.

Some say to change the .profile file and some say to change the .bash_profile file. What is the difference?

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`.profile` works with `sh` or `bash`. However `.bash_profile` is bash-specific and will override `.profile` if present.

Comment: I believe that .bash_profile overrides .profile, and not the other way around, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: I just tested and .bash_profile does indeed appear to override .profile

Comment: when `.bashrc` file will be executed in the order?

Comment: On Mac it never will. You need to add `source ~/.bashrc` inside your `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 50):

I believe mac OS X environment checks `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, `.profile` in this order. It will run whichever is the highest in the hierarchy, so, if you have `.bash_profile`, it will not check `.profile`.

Comment: I can confirm that. I just installed google cloud sdk which created a .bash_profile when I was using .profile for all my other variables and a lot of applications stopped to work.

Comment: I believe .bashrc should be in that list?

Comment: @tscizzle - The mentioned list is valid for a login shell

Comment: to make the answer complete - could you please add the role of .bashrc ? I read that there is a distinction between "login shells" and "non login interactive shells" and I don't really understand it -- but still you could add clarification - that all those .bash_xxxxx are for "login shells" (whatever they may be) and .bashrc for the others.