# -bash: ruby: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rbenv

```
hyperrjas@serv1:~$ rbenv global
1.9.3-p392
hyperrjas@serv1:~$ rbenv local
1.9.3-p392
hyperrjas@serv1:~$ which ruby-build
/usr/local/bin/ruby-build
hyperrjas@serv1:~$ rbenv versions
* 1.9.3-p392 (set by /home/hyperrjas/.ruby-version)
hyperrjas@serv1:~$ rbenv version
1.9.3-p392 (set by /home/hyperrjas/.ruby-version)
hyperrjas@serv1:~$ rbenv rehash
hyperrjas@serv1:~$ ruby -v
-bash: ruby: command not found
hyperrjas@serv1:~$ env | grep PATH
PATH=/home/hyperrjas/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript
hyperrjas@serv1:~$ export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
hyperrjas@serv1:~$ ruby -v
-bash: ruby: command not found
```

**I'm working with ubuntu 12.04.**

This is my `~/.profile` file:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

I have installed ruby last version with rbenv and when I try `ruby -v` I get `-bash: ruby: command not found`

Comment: I think you need to run a command that adds ruby to your $PATH, unfortunately I have no idea what that command is, good luck!

Comment: FWIW, you may consider moving toward [RVM](http://rvm.io)

Comment: RVM and rbenv are equally as good. rbenv is lighter weight, and less complicated, with fewer moving parts. RVM has a lot of capabilities, and a lot more things to go wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

rbenv needs these at the end of your **~/.bash_profile**:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Use `grep rbenv ~/.bash_profile` to  see if they're there.

If not, run:

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
exec $SHELL -l
```

and you should be up and running.

See steps 2 and 3 in [the docs](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/) for more information.

Additional information on .bashrc, .bash_profile and .profile can be found in:

- [What's the difference between .bashrc, .bash_profile, and .environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment)
- [Difference between .profile and .bash_profile on Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751252/difference-between-profile-and-bash-profile-on-snow-leopard)
- https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40708/what-is-the-difference-between-profile-bashrc-bash-profile-gnomer

Comment: `rbenv init` enables shims and autocompletion.

Comment: I don't understand why in rbenv doc specify if you are running ubuntu it is possible add **Ubuntu note**: `Modify your ~/.profile instead of ~/.bash_profile.`. If with `~/.profile` is not working why is specified in doc?

Comment: Good. I think you'll find rbenv is great for "normal" development. I used RVM for a long time and decided it was getting too big for my needs.

Answer (score 3):

Run `env | grep PATH` and make sure that you have `$HOME/.rbenv/bin` in your PATH.

If it is not, add this to  ~/.bash_profile.

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Thank you I have tried with this but I get the same result. This is my  `env | grep PATH` `PATH=/home/hyperrjas/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript` Thank you

Comment: Open a new terminal window. Your changes will applied at the next terminal window login.