# Setting environment variables in either .bashrc or .bash_profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables

I'm following the **Learn Ruby on Rails - RailsApps** tutorial. In the config section, it talks about opening either `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` and seeing a export path command. Both of those files are blank. And the tutorial is asking me to record environment variables in one of those two files. I am assuming the file to be the one with an export path. Since both of my files are blank does it matter which file I record the environment variables to?
Running OS X 10.9.4 and using `rvm`.

These are the variables:

```
export GMAIL_USERNAME="example@gmail.com"
export GMAIL_PASSWORD="Your_Password"
export MAILCHIMP_API_KEY="Your_MailChimp_API_Key"
export MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID="Your_List_ID"
export OWNER_EMAIL="example@gmail.com"
```

Comment: What OS are you on? It's not common to have empty ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile.

Comment: Check those files in your home directory, e.g. `vi ~/.bashrc`. If you're just on the local machine it doesn't matter which file you put them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add those things to `.bashrc`, if it doesn't exist in your home directory just create it.If you are wondering this are called enviorment variables and by `export` you make them available to the shell when your `.bashrc` is ran. This happens because every time you open a terminal your `.bashrc` is executed.It is not that simple but if you want deeper understanding read about `bash` and `unix` shell.

Answer (score 2):

That tutorial was probably referring to Linux. In OS X it's more common to place this information into `~/.profile` (Although adding to `~/.bash_rc` should still work). This will only work if your `~/.bash_profile` does not exist ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751252/difference-between-profile-and-bash-profile-on-snow-leopard))

Chances are your `.profile` will not be empty either.

Comment: I think this is the case in MACOS.  It might vary on the linux dist.