# Mac OS X: How do I run binaries that are outside usr/local/bin?

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, binaryfiles, bin

I have installed a program that did not automatically put its binaries into usr/local/bin for me. This means that "command not found" errors happen very often whenever I run scripts in that program. I can fix this by copy-pasting the binaries into the usr/local/bin directory, but I don't want to do this every single time, for every single binary. What would be a more efficient way to make the scripts work?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executables are simply resolved via the `$PATH` variable. It's set to something like

```
PATH="/bin:/usr/local/bin:..."
```

(Try `$ echo $PATH`.)

When you enter a command:

```
$ foo
```

each path will be tried in turn and the first matching executable will be executed.

```
/bin/foo 
/usr/local/bin/foo
```

To execute something outside the default path, simply enter the whole path to the executable:

```
$ /home/me/bin/foo
$ cd /home/me/bin
$ ./foo
```

If you find that you need to do that often and want the shortcut, alter your path:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/me/bin"
```

(Put this in your shell startup script like `~/.profile` to automate that.)

Alternatively, symlink the executable to somewhere in your path:

```
$ ln -s /home/me/bin/foo /usr/local/bin/foo
```

Comment: OSX doesn't have a `~/.profile` (it's `~/.bash_profile`) and your symlink arguments are back-to-front.

Comment: OS X *does* have `~/.profile`, I'm using it. And `ln` is defined as `ln [-Ffhinsv] source_file [target_file]`.

Comment: Of course you can use `~/.profile` but using `~/.bash_profile` would appear to be the more normal option. As for the `ln` command line, I don't think you've thought that through properly. Hang on; unless the new binary is in `/home/me/bin`?

Comment: OK, I see.  I misunderstood.  I would have expected `$HOME/bin` to be in the path anyway.

Comment: Yes, the `ln` example builds on the previous example with `~/bin`.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751252/difference-between-profile-and-bash-profile-on-snow-leopard - both are valid options.

Comment: I'm voting to close the question anyway; this is basic user-stuff.

Comment: Can't really disagree with that unfortunately. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add the directory containing the binary to your `$PATH` environment variable by editing `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/your/new/path
```

You can also edit `/etc/paths` or add a file to `/etc/paths.d`, but you need to have admin privilege to do that.