# setting GOPATH doesn't have any effect

Tags: macos, go, environment-variables

On MacOS Yosemite, inside my `.profile` file I have set:

```
GOPATH="$HOME/go"
PATH="$PATH:$GOPATH/bin"
```

But `go env` outputs:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

I also created `.bashrc` inside my home folder, added the GOPATH variable to the file, but the end result is the same. And it seems that until I set this path variable, I'm unable to install any Go package. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `export GOPATH="$HOME/go"` in your .profile?

Comment: @DaveMackintosh it works. But how can I add it to .profile so I don't have to run it every time I need it?

Comment: Does anything in that file work? If not, rename it to `.bash_profile`

Comment: I have the DOCKER config in that file, and other PATH variables, an it does indeed work. But I'll try to rename it and see if Go works.

Comment: Don't bother renaming it, just change them to `export GOPATH="$HOME/go"` and `export PATH="$PATH:$GOPATH/bin"`

Comment: Although, review this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751252/difference-between-profile-and-bash-profile-on-snow-leopard for the differences between `.profile` and `.bash_profile` and you can make a decision between which one to use. I personally use `.bash_profile`

Comment: @DaveMackintosh `export` fixes it. What's the difference?

Comment: @lucassp without export the variable remains in the scope of the current script. you should have export before any global env var declaration in your profile file.

Comment: When you just set a variable it tells the shell to load everything to the right of the `=` into the variable to the left of the `=` whereas `export` is a `'builtin'`. The difference being when shell invokes an application it is passed all of the environmentals, this is everything that is `'exported'` including your `$PATH` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `export` on your declaration, the reason being that when you start an application from shell your app isn't receiving your updated `$PATH`. When you `export` a variable it adds it to the list of environmentals sent to all future application invocations.

See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Environment) for more information on the environment within a shell.

Also, try investigating the choices between `.profile` and `.bash_profile` since if you have a similar export in your `.bash_profile` and you don't append to the `$PATH` it will overwrite your export. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751252/difference-between-profile-and-bash-profile-on-snow-leopard) for more info.

`.profile` is shell *and* bash compatible where as `.bash_profile` is only bash compatible (if you don't know the difference, use `.bash_profile`).