# Installed Java 7 on Mac OS X but Terminal is still using version 6

Tags: java, macos, java-7

I've installed JDK 7u7 downloaded from oracle's website. But after installation, the terminal is still showing java version 6

```
$java -version
java version "1.6.0_35"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_35-b10-428-11M3811)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.10-b01-428, mixed mode)
```

any idea why java 7 is not showing up?

**Ans:
OK, the problem has been resolved. Here is the answer:
I found that my Terminal has a .bash_profile and the java home variable is set to 1.6**

```
export JAVA_HOME="/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home"
```

So this is the line causing the problem every time I opened a new terminal window.
Simply remove this line will solve the problem. You still need to follow what @aleroot said, but if that doesn't work for you, check the .bash_profile (or .bashrc) setting file to see if you've previously exported any java version.

Comment: I had this problem but I only updated the JRE and not the JDK. Once I updated the JDK it showed the correct version.

Comment: Migrate this to Ask Different?

Comment: Just to draw some extra attention to @Mazzy's comment, that's an easy mistake to make. Downloading JRE v7 will cause version 7 to appear when running the online version checker, or the Java control panel thingy, but when invoking Java from the command line you'll be running the older version from your previously installed JDK. So double-check to make sure you installed the JDK and not just the JRE.

Comment: The best way to solve this is to use the `export JAVA_HOME` approach, as [detailed here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6588410/26510) in a slightly more flexible way.

Comment: @CamJackson  On Mac Sierra I've /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines which has jdk and System Preferences > Java what's different between these 2 ?

Comment: Let me stress this in capital letters: MANY PEOPLE LANDING ON THIS PAGE WILL JUST NEED TO DOWNLOAD AND INSTALL THE LATEST JDK. THE JAVA CONTROL PANEL ONLY UPDATES THE JRE.

Comment: Oracle's management of Java versions on MacOS is AMAZINGLY inconsistent and confusing. And it's been terrible for a &)*^#$ decade!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Because you need to enter in Java Preferences pane and flag only the JVM 7 in this way :

[image: Java Preferences]

To easily and quickly open the **Java Preferences** pane in Mac OS X you can simply call spotlight with <kbd>⌘</kbd>**+**<kbd>SPACE</kbd> and type *System Preferences* it will show up in the last row of the window.

Comment: Open Spotlight(CTRL+SPACE) type JAva Preferences and you will find it as first result .

Comment: yes, found it. but still version 1.6 in terminal, do i need to reboot or something

Comment: This panel does no longer exist in 10.8. Alternatives?

Comment: @Pepijn  Install the latest JDK from Oracle, it will set the java 7 as default ...

Comment: @Pepijn The panale is history as of Mac OSX 10.8.2 and there isn't really a need for it anymore. Instead you have to use `export JAVA_HOME=\`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7\`` to switch to the latest Java 7 JDK from Oracle.

Comment: @cr0nicz Not on all versions — and further, the spotlight key-command is customizable.

Comment: I think they got rid of Java Preferences at some point. It's not found by Spotlight on my box. Running 10.8.5.

Comment: You can find the exact location of JAVA_HOME under -> system preferences -> java. Click "Java" tab. Click view. The Path variable shows your JAVA_HOME (tile /Home).

Comment: There is nothing mentioning Java in System preferences (10.10.5)

Comment: This discussion might help too: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6527269?start=0 Install the JDK, not the JRE. It worked for me very well. Mac OS X 10.11.6.

Answer (score 299):

Oracle's installer puts java inside the `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin`. And it doesn't overwrite `/usr/bin/java`. So, if you issue a

```
whereis java
```

in the terminal, it'll return /usr/bin/java. (which in turn points to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/java`, which is Apple's 1.6 version).

So, if you want to use the new java version, replace the `/usr/bin/java` symlink so that it points to `/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java` instead:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/java
sudo ln -s /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java /usr/bin
```

Comment: I've done this on a few machines and I always forget how! :)
Thanks for this. I'm now running java 7 in osx 10.8.4.

Comment: Here is the command: sudo ln -s /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java /usr/bin

Comment: You should also make sure you have the JDK and not just the JRE as the Plug-In will show Java 7 if only the JRE is installed, so it may be better to soft-link to the JDK version, e.g., /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java . Note that it's also possible an apple update may revert the symlink.

Comment: Viktor's command works. But you may also need to be sure you remove the existing java symlink `rm /usr/bin/java`

Comment: Until Oracle folks improve this process, here's a HOWTO of the whole process of installing java on an osx system, up until and including this final symlink step: https://gist.github.com/johan/10590467

Comment: Remember you would also have to update the links for jar, jarsigner, javac, javadoc, javah, javap, javaws, jcmd, jconsole, jdb, jhat, jinfo, jmap, jmc, jps, jrunscript, jsadebugd, jstack, jstat, jstatd, and jvisualvm to provide a coherent environment.  That makes this option rather burdensome.

Comment: This works for java 1.8.0 update as well and now suspecting this will be the way to for some time. Why won't Apple just comply?

Comment: Should the symlink be /usr/bin/java instead of /usr/bin?

Comment: i got `rm: /usr/bin/java: Operation not permitted`

Comment: It should be noted that as of OS X El Capitan (10.11), files like `/usr/bin/java` can only be modified by Apple-signed processes unless you boot into recovery mode. It's probably a better idea to make sure `/usr/local/bin` is on your path and symlink into that directory.

Comment: Installing JDK fixed it for me. This way seems like a hack as we're not linking all the other binaries as @JoeAtzberger has mentioned.

Comment: @Aditya This is due to the new System Integration Protection (a.k.a rootless) that is now on El Capitan. See this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007889/move-usr-bin-java-in-terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007889/move-usr-bin-java-in-terminal) on how to disable it.

Comment: I would suggest creating the symlink under `/usr/local/bin` because of the rootless policy

Comment: Or `export PATH="/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin:$PATH"
`

Comment: @Mick You should make your comment an answer as it is more correct than this answer and resolves the issues better than other answers

Comment: For me following commands worked.                                               sudo rm /usr/bin/java
sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java  java

Answer (score 115):

Install the [**JDK 7**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and this problem will solve itself.

Be sure to get the Java Development Kit (JDK) which includes compilers and stuff like that, rather than just the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) .

Comment: instal the full JDK, not only the JRE.

Comment: Confirmed OK on OSX 10.9.4.  It doesn't change the /usr/bin link, it changes stuff underneath it. So 
`/usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
# But:
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java -version
java version "1.7.0_67"`

Comment: Also worked for JDK 1.8 -- (install JDK 1.8 instead of JRE 1.8)

Comment: I tried to install Java 1.8, but that didn't work on El Capitan. Installing 1.7 solved my problems.

Answer (score 105):

`vi ~/.bash_profile`

add

`` export  JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7` ``

This tells your `/usr/bin/java` link target to use the latest Java 7 Package installed in

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`

So for JDK `1.7.0_17` `JAVA_HOME` would be:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home`

Note: There were a lot of change in this area recently to move Mac OS X from Appels own System integrated Java packages to Oracle based Java Packages. The above solution is working fine as of Mac OS X 10.8.2

Comment: +1 for this answer which is imo the correct one because it works on versions of Mac OS before and after 'Java Preferences' was removed, and by showing the "-v" option it demonstrates how you can use java 6 even if java 7 is installed (which is what I want). Hence on my Mac running Lion (10.7.5) I use the same command with "-v 1.6". This is crucial because I need Java 6 and Oracle doesnt provide one for Mac OS - only Java 7, and this allows me to use the installed JAva 6 even though Java 7 is installed.

Comment: Also, to make it more flexible: http://mikemainguy.blogspot.com/2014/11/easily-changing-java-versions-in-osx.html

Comment: additional info [can be found here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6588410/26510) for this awesome answer!

Comment: This worked for me in Sierra 10.12 after installing the 1.8 JKD the export worked by changing 1.7 to 1.8. Great answer using the java_home utility!!

Comment: For .cshrc `setenv JAVA_HOME \`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 15\``

Answer (score 56):

In my case, the issue was that Oracle was installing it to a different location than I was used to.

Download from Oracle: http://java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp?locale=en

1. Verify that it's installed properly by looking in System Prefs:

   - Command-Space to open Spotlight, type 'System Preferences', hit enter.
   - Click Java icon in bottom row. After the Java Control Panel opens, click 'Java' tab, 'View...', and verify that your install worked.  You can see a 'Path' there also, which you can sub into the commands below in case they are different than mine.
2. Verify that the version is as you expect (sub in your path as needed):

   /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
3. Create link from /usr/bin/java to your new install

   sudo ln -fs /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java /usr/bin/java
4. Sanity check your version:

   java -version

Comment: Worked for me too, I also tried the other explanation but with Maverix there is no panel where you can select a version number and also changing the .bash_profile didn't work. PERFECT!

Comment: Eclipse is not seeing 1.7 under compiler

Comment: Worked for me!.
Before = 1.6.0_65 and After using this solution = 1.7.0_60.... thanks! :)

Comment: but eclipse gives error like still 'the jvm shared library does not contain the jni_createjavavm symbol' ....:(

Comment: Genius this is awesome!

Comment: Thanks for the help! Nothing else worked except this. Running Yosemite

Comment: getting Operation Not permitted

Comment: For those getting "Operation Not permitted" with Mojave you may need to grant full disk access privilege to Terminal via Preferences -> Security & Privacy

Answer (score 36):

I had run into a similar issue with terminal not updating the java version to match the version installed on the mac.

There was no issue with the JAVA_HOME environmental variable being set

I have come up with a temporary and somewhat painful but working solution.

In you .bash_profile add the line:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

(This is the path on my machine but may be different on yours, make sure to get yours. The paths should match up to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/)

the run `source ~/.bash_profile`

As I mentioned this is a temporary band-aid solution because the java home path is being hard-coded. There is really no way to set the path to get the latest as that is what Apple is supposedly doing for terminal already and the issue is that Apple's java_home environment variable is not getting updated.

Comment: The directory is empty. $ ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/

Comment: You probably have an issue with where you installed java 7.

Please go to [oracle's website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html#jdk-7u11-oth-JPR).  

Click on the "Java SE Development Kit 7u11" link, accept the license agreement, and download "jdk-7u11-macosx-x64.dmg".  

Use the dmg to install Java 7 and this should put it in your JavaVirtualMachines directory.

Comment: This is one solution on Mojave 10.14.1 in early 2019

Answer (score 26):

Since El Capitan, it is difficult to delete the `/usr/bin/java` symlink, because of the introduction of the new "rootless" policy.

Therefore, I simply added the path to the latest java version (in my case this is `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin`) to the `PATH` in my `.bashrc` file:

```
# Use latest java version
export PATH=/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin:$PATH
```

To reload your `.bashrc` file for the current session, run `source ~/.bashrc` in the shell. You only have to do this for sessions that had been started before changing the `.bashrc` file.

Now the latest version is used, when you use `java` in the shell.

Comment: This particular solution worked for me on my mac os x el capitan. I did not bypass the the security set up on el capitan, but installed java version 1.8. Doing export JAVA_HOME=/my specific path etc etc/ did not work (after going to preferences and locating the path to 1.8). Please note 1.6 is still installed. I had to create a .bashrc file  and set the path as described here. I ran java -version and shazzam! it worked.

Comment: I so wanted this to work as I'm on El Capitan and can't get any other solution to function. I created a '.bashrc' file and added the line as above, but if I type 'java -version' I still get 1.6. Anything I might have overlooked?

Comment: @user3810073 maybe you need to run `source .bashrc`, in order to reload the contents of .bashrc

Comment: Worked for me. I added the line to .bash_profile (in the home directory of my user), then source .bash_profile. Then java -version gave me the latest one. Thanks!

Comment: This can also be achieved by symlinking to `/usr/local/bin` like this:

    
    `sudo ln -sf "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java" /usr/local/bin/java`
    

That assuming `/usr/local/bin` is before `/usr/bin` in your `$PATH` which should be by default.

Answer (score 21):

**Update**

```
brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk
brew cask install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28635465

**Old version**
For me the easiest and cleanest way to go is to install Java using homebrew like described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28635465

```
brew update
brew cask install java
```

Answer (score 14):

You can execute following command in your terminal :

```
export PATH="/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin:$PATH"
```

And this replaces the java old with new one.

Comment: Weirdly it replaces but then if I close terminal and open again, it again shows older version

Comment: thats true. so werid. very temporary solution

Comment: add that to .bashrc file then `source ~/.bashrc` to make it permanent

Answer (score 13):

The basic issue: `/usr/bin/java` is pointing to one provided by OSX itself initially (`/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java`)
We need to point this to the one downloaded by the JDK installer. The below steps are for OSX 10.10.4 Yosemite.

- Open System Preferences -> select Java. The Java window opens.
- Click on Java tab at the top. Click on 'View' button.
- The Java Runtime Environment Settings tab opens as below:
  [image: JRE Settings tab]
- Double click on the `Path` item and copy the path (cmd+c). This is the latest one installed by the JDK installer/updater. In my case, the path was `/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java`
- Open terminal. In this step, we are going to point (symbolic link, `ln -s` command) the system java binary to the latest one, which we discovered in the previous step. Run the below command:

`sudo ln -s /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java /usr/bin/java`

Thats it. To verify, you can just run
`java -version`
on the terminal. It should output the latest version that you installed/updated to.

Comment: Works for me, except that I had to add -f to ln command. Otherwise if failed with ln: /usr/bin/java: File exists

Comment: in my case I'd to use `usr/local/bin` instead of `usr/bin` in terminal command

Comment: I am getting "operation not permitted".

Comment: Obtaining the path in this manner is ideal. I then was able to export it and reload bashrc to resolve the version issue. In my case I was migrating from version 7 to 8 on Mojave 10.14.1

Answer (score 10):

I did

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
```

and that fixed my Java 8 issue.

before:

```
java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01, mixed mode)
```

after:

```
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: The `/usr/libexec/java_home` is a very good indication, thanks!

Comment: Did the job for my after reading tons of possible solutions! Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml is a nice place to understand, while Apple is stopping support to Java, why Java Preferences doesn't exist anymore and rely on System_Preferences => Java => Java if Java 7 from Oracle is installed.

Comment: This is good information, but you should really provide more details than just a link.  If the link is broken in the future, your answer really won't be very useful.

Answer (score 7):

May I suggest you to have a look at the tool [Jenv](https://github.com/hikage/jenv)

This will allow you to switch at any time between your installed JVMs.

Simply as:

```
jenv global oracle-1.7
```

then later for test purpose:

```
jenv global oracle-1.6
```

And you have much more commands available.

Comment: +1 for this answer as you can utilize Homebrew, if you're using it already in your OS X system. Much cleaner than others I say. More info here:

http://www.jenv.be/

Answer (score 6):

Hard-coding the JAVA_HOME path might not be the best idea. The `/usr/libexec/java_home` utility sill works for me on Mac OSX Lion 10.7.5 and JDK 1.7.0_13. According to its man page, it is meant to be used with Apple's old Java Preferences pane, but it appears to be working with the replacement provided by Oracle (Java Control Panel). For example running `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` lists all installed JDKs (both 1.6.* and 1.7.*) on my machine.

So, as discussed in other threads (e.g. [What should I set JAVA_HOME to on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348842/what-should-i-set-java-home-to-on-osx)), I would still recommend adding the following line to your .bash_profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Comment: I would agree with your comment here, because that is best practice, but for some reason the java_home environment variable is not being set correctly which is why this does not work. I believe in Apple's latest update your suggestion is the default action for JAVA_HOME in terminal and other related applications by default.

Comment: @Derek What do you exactly mean on "the java_home environment variable is not being set correctly"? According to [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Java/Java_OSX2012006Java_MacOSX10.6Update11RN/NewandNoteworthy/NewandNoteworthy.html) the `/usr/libexec/java_home` utility is meant to be working also with java 7 versions, and it returns the path to the most up-to-date JDK installed. It does perfectly work on my machine.

Comment: yes it is supposed to work however it does not for people with the problem that pepijin had mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

This is nuts! How does Oracle provide an installer that doesn't install anything!?

Anyways for me it was:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/java
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java /usr/bin/java
```

where 1.8.0_31 is your installed java version...

Comment: Why does Apple not provide a proper method?

Answer (score 6):

In case if you have several Java versions on your machine and you want to choose it dynamically at runtime, i.e, in my case, I have two versions:

```
ls -la /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel    96B Nov 16  2014 jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel    96B Mar  1  2015 jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/
```

You can change them by modifying the /etc/profile content. Just add (or modify) the following two lines at the end of the file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=YOUR_JAVA_PATH/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

In my case, it should be like the following if I want to use:

Java 7:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Java 8:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

After saving the file, **please run** `source /etc/profile` and it should work. Here are results when I use the first and second option accordingly:

Java 7:

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
```

Java 8:

```
java -version 
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
```

The process is similar if your java folder is located in different locations.

Answer (score 5):

## Simple Solution

```
export PATH="/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Awesome. This solution made my day. Thanks a lot Mick

Answer (score 3):

I think you can try to install jdk not jre. By installing jdk, the java in /usr/bin/java will be replaced, and all library will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Homebrew installed, you can install **java-switcher** to change Java default version more quickly

```sh
brew tap andycillin/tap
brew install java-switcher
```

Then you can use just one command to switch your default Java version.

```sh
java-switcher 1.7
```

or

```sh
java-switcher 10
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, this was easy.

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because your .bash_profile is not reflecting changes.To reflect it, just use the following command

```
$ source .bash_profile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run this command to find the version of Java that's under /Library/Internet Plugins/:

```
defaults read /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Info.plist CFBundleVersion
```

Answer (score 0):

Since i have not faced this issue , I am taking a hunch --

Can you please try this :

Where does the soft link "java_home" point to :

```
ls -lrt /usr/libexec/java_home
```

Output : (Stunted)
    lrwxr-xr-x java_home ->      /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java_home

**ls -lrt /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
    My MAC Produces the following :

```
 lrwxr-xr-x CurrentJDK ->
 /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents**

 lrwxr-xr-x   Current -> A
 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 18 14:39 1.6.0 -> CurrentJDK
 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 18 14:39 1.6 -> CurrentJDK
 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 18 14:39 1.5.0 -> CurrentJDK
 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 18 14:39 1.5 -> CurrentJDK
 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 18 14:39 1.4.2 -> CurrentJDK
 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 18 14:39 1.4 -> CurrentJDK
```

Based on this , we might get a hint to proceed further ?

Comment: read some commentaries on the Internet about Java 7 issues with MAC-OSX and it shows blocked.Refer this : http://www.grep.dk/tag/xprotect-meta-plist/. In XProtect.meta.plist I have Java 7 and Flash listed.Until is playing the Vulnerability Police

Answer (score 0):

i resolved this issue by re installing Yosemite and then cross check java version on terminal (java -version) and (javac -version) .It work perfectly now.It is not changing to java 7 as version 6 still present on (command + n) libray>java>javavirtualmachine>your javac current version.you need to address to java home .

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue with
`sudo rm /usr/bin/java`

And I downloaded and installed the last Java SE Runtime Environment:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

`sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java /usr/bin/java` did not work for me because I got `Operation not permitted`. El Capitan now protects certain system directories in "rootless" mode (a.k.a. System Integrity Protection). It is applicable to macOS Sierra, and probably new macOS versions for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

Installing through distributed JDK DMG from the Oracle site auto-updates everything for me. I have seen (in El Capitan) updating through `System Preferences > Java` do updates but that do not reflect to command line. Installing through DMG does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Check JDK versions installed:

```
$ ls  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
jdk-11.0.2.jdk  jdk1.8.0_91.jdk
```

Now in your `~/.bashrc` export `JAVA_HOME` specifying the version:

```
if [ -e /usr/libexec/java_home ]; then
  export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11)
fi
```

Source the bashrc file and the Java version will be updated:

```
$ java -version
java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

### The latest 100% effective method:

in bash:

```sh
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

add

```sh
export PATH="/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin:$PATH"
```

- `:wq` to save
- cmd+q force quit bash
- open bash again, and type in `java -version`

But actually this path points to jre not jdk.

If you want to point the path to JDK, you need

1. Make sure you have installed JDK not a single JRE runtime
2. replace previous path to `PATH="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk"`, you can go to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` to make sure you have installed the version of JDK you expected.