# Installed Java 7, but interminal still Java 6

Tags: java, macos, osx-lion

I've installed Java 7 on my Mac (10.7.5), but in the terminal there is still java 6.

> java version "1.6.0_37"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)

There will be no problem with the version 6 on terminal, if I always got that errors when I tried to install a java application ([LatexDraw](http://latexdraw.sourceforge.net/download.html)):

> : CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0
>
> : CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0
>
> : CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0
>
> : CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0

The problem is related to instability of java 6 inferred from [this link](https://discussions.apple.com/message/18394472#18394472)

I've read this [installed-java-7-on-mac-osx-but-terminal-is-still-using-version-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757558/installed-java-7-on-mac-osx-but-terminal-is-still-using-version-6) and also try to change my Java version by using `export JAVA_HOME="/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home"`, but in my folder `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions`, there is no version 1.7, only versions under 1.6 ??? So, how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Thanks @JanDvorak, I did post my question to "Super User"

Comment: @chipbk10 - Well wait for them to answer!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve in this way :

- Get the path of your installed Java 7 JRE in this way :

  /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7
- Set the output of the previous command as `JAVA_HOME` variale(for example in my case) :

  export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07.jdk/Contents/Home

Take a look at [this post](http://blog.hgomez.net/blog/2012/07/20/understanding-java-from-command-line-on-osx/) for more information ...

Comment: You usually want to do even this: `export JAVA_HOME=\`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7\``

Comment: I just installed the 1.7 jdk on mavericks and I don't have /usr/libexec/java_home on my system. Why not?