# How to use Java 7 from Eclipse in OSX Lion

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to upgrade to Java 7 on my 2010 macbook pro running OSX Lion. I downloaded jdk 7u15 and it goes through the entire install procedure flawlessly. However when I went to add it into Eclipse I found it was not under System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines as was Java 6. I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: This should be on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Issue with Java 7 installation on MAC : There are reports of vulnerability with Java 7 . Check out Xprotect.plist on your system. Checkout this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757558/installed-java-7-on-mac-osx-but-terminal-is-still-using-version-6/14856370#14856370

Answer (score 1):

On Mountain Lion, mine is in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_15.jdk/

Comment: If this doesn't work, search the file system for a directory containing "jdk1.7".

Comment: You should check Xprotect.plist on your system of the reported vulnerabilities

Answer (score 1):

Use `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` on a Mac to see all JDK versions installed. (JDK 7 versions reside normally under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`).