# unsupported major minor version 51.0, but my JRE is up to date

Tags: java

I built a Java application in Eclipse on Windows 7.
I have Mac OSX 10.7.4 on a VMWare machine.

I built the app with JDK 1.7. I have JRE 1.7 on my Windows and the app works fine.
I have Java 1.7 installed on the Mac VM Machine.

When launching the app on my Mac VM Machine, I get a "unspported major.minor version 51.0" error.

I know that this error means I don't have the right JRE to run my JAR file, but I do have JRE 7 installed (I installed it today).

My Application uses Apache FTP Client libraries but they are all included in the JAR file (I exported the Eclipse project into a Runnable JAR File, with all the required libraries).

Comment: You may *have* it, but you're running it with something other than a JRE that supports 51.

Comment: Make sure you have only one JRE installed on your system. It's a common issue on Windows to leave Java Update Checker "on" and accept an automatic update - it actually installs the new JRE along the existing ones. And which JRE is the default is a mystery.

Comment: Oops ok didn't know pressing Enter would send the comment. Anyways, so I am sure that the JRE used is Java 7 on my Windows Machine, because to run my App, I have to have the JRE 7 installed (or it wouldn't work on my other PCs). So the problem is happening on the mac.

Comment: This error means that your Mac has a java version older than 1.7. Maybe you have two JVMs on Mac?

Comment: I uninstalled Java 7, then re-installed, then rebooted OSX but still, I get the same error.

Comment: Ok, well, I checked the java version with "java -version" in the terminal, and you were right, the version is 1.6 even though I installed java 1.7. Weird ! I guess this is due to VMWare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this issue can be found on this post : [Installed Java 7 on Mac OS X but Terminal is still using version 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757558/installed-java-7-on-mac-os-x-but-terminal-is-still-using-version-6).

Thanks for everyone's help.