# Java runtime environment error

Tags: java, terminal

This may seem trivial but I haven't been able to find a fix.

I've installed the latest Java runtime environment  but when I run `java -version` on the command line, I still get `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)`

However, when I test my Java version in browser, it works fine.

How can I get Terminal using the latest java version?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Mac OS X 10.9

Comment: what is this "How can I get Terminal"

Comment: Begin -> Control Panel -> Java -> Java Tab -> "See" Button -> And choose the runtime environment.

Comment: what build are you expecting? 1.7 stands for jre 7

Comment: I'm expecting build 53. And in Settings it's set to be using build 53

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installed Java 7 on Mac OS X but Terminal is still using version 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757558/installed-java-7-on-mac-os-x-but-terminal-is-still-using-version-6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [Installed Java 7 on Mac OS X but Terminal is still using version 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757558/installed-java-7-on-mac-os-x-but-terminal-is-still-using-version-6)

maybe you need to select the java version you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using windows..
from your command line

```
echo %PATH%
```

make sure your java PATH is pointing your latest java bin folder.

I am not sure about the Mac but Can you verify if you have symlink setup under /usr/bin?

ex. /usr/bin/java -> java_path

Maybe you can change this symlink to point to the latest java you have installed.

Comment: See the above comment he is using mac