# GWT installation issue with eclipse...?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin

I am using os x 10.9.1
I need to install **google plugin for eclipse** for using google web toolkit. I have eclipse **juno**, so I just follow [link](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.2) for install it. But it not work for me, not go ahead because below issue
[image]

So, I move to install latest version of eclipse **kepler** and follow [link](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.3) for install plugins. After all installation finished with some different issues and restart eclipse **kepler** it shows me java version error.
[image]

And same thing show me when I check through terminal
[image]

but when I check in my java preference, it show me latest version installed on my mac.
[image]

*********************Edited from here*********************

After downloading java 7 and installing it(as per one of comment in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757558/installed-java-7-on-mac-os-x-but-terminal-is-still-using-version-6)),again check in terminal give me new version

[image]

I restart my eclipse and starting error is not there. Just go ahead and create GWT project, and now
[image]

Stuck again...!?!

Comment: im not expert on mac, but is it posiible you have installed two versions of java on your machine? check property JAVA_HOME and check is it pointing to java6 or java7

Comment: Take a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757558/installed-java-7-on-mac-os-x-but-terminal-is-still-using-version-6

Comment: Please find Edited from here at end of question, for some edits

Answer (score 0):

Open `eclipse.ini` form your eclipse folder and set the following parameter as shown in image

```
-vm
//your java7-dir/bin/javaw.exe (use mac javaw in your case)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello sumit, I tried what you said as per mac os. But not work for me still having "App engine requires Java 1.7 or later" error in eclipse.