# Problems updating Java on OSX

Tags: java, macos, bash

I need to update my version of Java to 1.8. I install it successfully, but when I run...

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
```

I know this is something to do with changing my bash path but, after hours of googling, I'm pretty lost as to how to go about doing that. And I also can't find the location of the new version.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you have  a look to this answer?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757558/installed-java-7-on-mac-os-x-but-terminal-is-still-using-version-6

Answer (score 0):

Your JAVA_HOME needs to be set to the new java install.  I'm not on my Mac at the moment, but it should be located in your .bash_profile.