# JavaVirtualMachines still says "1.6.0.jdk" after installing Java 7 JDK on OS X

Tags: java, android, macos

I am trying to download the Java 7 jdk for Android Studio on my mac because "Android-21 requires compiling with JDK 7"

I have downloaded and installed the Java 7 jdk numerous times and restarted my laptop, but when I go to check the jdk in /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines it says 1.6.0.jdk

Correct me if I'm wrong, but 1.6.0 is the Java 6 jdk, right?

and is there a way to install it manually?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757558/installed-java-7-on-mac-os-x-but-terminal-is-still-using-version-6?rq=1 for a probable solution. Everyone who does Android work on a mac runs into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not in 
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

But in
Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

If you take the folder structure at your root There will be two folders
1. System
2. Library

I am talking about the 2nd one. Not the Library folder in Systems folder

Use this command on terminal to find your JDK location

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean I can delete the java from my systems folder?

Comment: I don't recommend it.

Comment: Okay, last question, I saw in that folder I had 4 different jdk's. Do I need all of them?

Comment: It depends. If some of your applications referring to one of them, then deleting on of them can cause you unpredictable errors.

Comment: Alrighty I'll just leave it as is for the time being, I know they say to avoid comments like "thanks" but thanks lol

Answer (score 0):

I have Java 7 on my Mac, but it's in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home.