# installing java 7 on Mavericks

Tags: java, macos

I have a new mac with Mavericks (ie without java). I installed java 8, but my grails project not supported java8, and I need to install java7. 
How I can to install java 7 manually (java installer will determine the java 8) *without* uninstalling existing java8?

Comment: See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installed Java 7 on Mac OS X but Terminal is still using version 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757558/installed-java-7-on-mac-os-x-but-terminal-is-still-using-version-6)

Answer (score 0):

1. check out which version is installed

   java -version
2. download and install the version 1.7 from the oracle servers

this should work

Comment: no. Java 7 installer will closed without installation java 7 after detecting installed java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Apple disabled older versions of Java. here is the link to the Oracle website. There are further information about new and old java jdk's on Apple Mac https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml