# Make Java 1.8 default on Mac OSX 10.9.5

Tags: java, macos

The Java Control Panel says I have Java 8 update 45.
Terminal says: java version "1.7.0_17".
Eclipse is using 1.7.0_17-b02.
Ho can I switch from Java 1.7 to 1.8 in terminal and Eclipse?

First I tried to make changes in Java Preferences, but is is missing from Utilities. Then I found [Installed Java 7 on Mac OS X but Terminal is still using version 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757558/) and have run

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/java
sudo ln -s /Library/Internet\ PlugIns/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java /usr/bin
```

Now terminal return java version "1.8.0_45", but Eclipse does not start:

The JVM shared library "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/../lib/server/libjvm.dylib"
does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol.

Comment: This probably belongs on superuser rather than stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

you need to uninstall jdk 1.7

Navigate to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` and remove the directory whose name matches the following format:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdkmajor.minor.macro[_update].jdk
```

For example, to uninstall 8u6:

```
% rm -rf jdk1.8.0_06.jdk
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is the proper way to uninstall something?