# Switching from java 1.6 to 1.8 on a mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, installation, java-8

I got a new mac and need to install java version 8. I downloaded it from oracle and when I run their app on their website, it says that I have the most recent version of java. When I run "java -version" is says that I am still using 1.6. How do I change this?

According to java control panel I have 1.8. However when working in eclipse it is still using 1.6.0_65. I tried uninstalling and it was unsuccessful.

My java virtual machine folder only contains 1.6.0.jdk. Do I need to move 1.8 to this folder?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757558/installed-java-7-on-mac-os-x-but-terminal-is-still-using-version-6 especially the second answer.

Comment: I tried that and am now getting an error when I run eclipse saying "The jvm shared library "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/contents/home/bin/.../lib/server/libjvm.dylib" does not contain the JNI_CreateJaveVM symbol "

Answer (score 3):

When you do java -version it gives the output of current jdk in use. For that to update we need to download jdk for mac here and install it.

Go to the following url and download the appropriate file. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- [Uninstall Java 6](https://superuser.com/questions/564687/how-do-i-uninstall-java6-from-mac-os-x).
- Alternatively, check this [script](http://www.jayway.com/2014/01/15/how-to-switch-jdk-version-on-mac-os-x-maverick/) (based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/490425/how-do-i-switch-between-java-7-and-java-6-on-os-x-10-8-2/568016#568016) at superuser.com) created by a colleague of mine if you would like to switch between multiple Java versions.

Answer (score 0):

For eclipse to use `Java 8` instead of `Java 6`, follow below steps:

1. Click `Eclipse` and then Select `Preferences`.
2. Search for `Compiler` in "type filter text" search box.
3. Select Compiler under Java.
4. Change `JDK` Compliance to `1.8`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jenv to switch between Java versions, it is like a Java environment manager. It is super easy to use and clean

For Mac, follow the steps:

```
brew install jenv

git clone https://github.com/gcuisinier/jenv.git ~/.jenv
```

Installation: If you are using bash follow these steps:

```
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

echo 'eval "$(jenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile

$ exec $SHELL -l
```

Add desired versions of JVM to jenv:

```
jenv add /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

jenv add /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Check the installed versions:

```
jenv versions
```

Set the Java version you want to use by:

```
jenv global oracle64-1.6.0
```