# Eclipse installation won't run on Macosx- default about JVM 1.6.0_65

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, java-6

I've got a question concerning installing Eclipse on machos 10.11.13. When I'm trying to install, I get a default saying that "Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version 1.7 or greater is required". but the problem is that I've got the newest version on Java installed on my laptop (version 1.8_077). I read that version 1.6 is Apple version of java and it cannot by uninstalled, so I'm stuck with no clue, I've already uninstalled java and installed in again using console, but nothing is working. Also I;ve put this "-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/bin" in the code of eclipse-instal.ini but it's still not working what should I do?????

Comment: Show us the exact contents of your 'eclipse.ini' file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installed Java 7 on Mac OS X but Terminal is still using version 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757558/installed-java-7-on-mac-os-x-but-terminal-is-still-using-version-6)

Comment: Download the 64-bit version

Comment: `-vm` should be followed by the actual VM binary's location, usually named `java`. The `bin` directory is not enough.

Comment: that's the content of eclipse.ini file, without my added line 

-startup
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
--launcher.appendVmargs
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-name
Eclipse Installer
-data

-vmargs
-Xms256M
-Xmx1024M
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts

@greg-449