# Choose updated Java SDK in mac from available different version

Tags: java, macos, nativescript, javac

I'm using mac machine for native-script development and while executing an program it thrown an java error that:

*Javac version **1.6.0_65** is not supported. You have to install at least **1.8.0**.*

so I checked with available install version on developer machine & found two different version detail:

`/usr/bin/java -version` Showing 1.6.

while `system preference -> java control panel -> update.` showing V1.8

any suggestion why two version !! Am I missing something here?

**Update[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14875241/2624806):** Following help to understand how mac handling this: `/usr/bin/java` is machine default location, and `/Library/Internet..` which is manage explicit.

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/java
sudo ln -s /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java /usr/bin
```

In my case I update default one with downloaded from internet.

Reference link **[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14875241/2624806)**, [**Link2**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14875241/2624806)

Comment: Though, primary issue has fixed. But still why mac managing multiple java version, it's confusing, what is purpose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `/usr/libexec/java_home` instead

```
> /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home
```

you can use it to set JAVA_HOME

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

then, you can put this one inside `~/.profile` so you have always JAVA_HOME set to most recent release.

Comment: You may be right. So in my case since I moved _/Library/Internet/.._ to _/usr/bin/_ so simply java -version giving me latest one which is downloaded from internet. BUT _/usr/libexec/java_home_ still contain 1.7 has highest version. So whoever use Environment variable JAVA_HOME they all get V1.7 only. Any suggestion over here.

Comment: From Oracle's page: "Do not attempt to uninstall Java by removing the Java tools from /usr/bin. This directory is part of the system software and any changes will be reset by Apple the next time you perform an update of the OS." Whenever you touch these files they can be changed. I suggest to install JDK from Oracle and set JAVA_HOME to most recent version.

Comment: How can be keep all version same, is this really required to keep multiple version ?

Comment: If you don't need them, you can always remove versions you don't need: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-macos.htm I guess this is more question to Apple and Oracle. And, note one more thing! To make things even more messy, you can have Java from Apple (different layout) and from Oracle. Oracle's layout is way more similar to other systems. You can take a look here for some info regarding Java struggles in macOS: http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3671

Comment: Thanks, well upgrade to new version from 1.7 to 1.8 fixed the issue, but why 2-3 java version issue is still remain in mind.