# JHipster: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, jhipster

I am trying to get familiar with Jhipster and I am having this error when I run my first `mvnw` is anyone had this already?:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/wrapper/MavenWrapperMain : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

I created the project by generating the sources on a github account.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have a pom.xml in your project? If so, you could try by specify 1.6 as "source" and "target" for the Maven entry.

Answer (score 2):

The error in this case means that Maven has classes compiled with Java 7, and thus needs Java 7 or higher (version 51.0), it seems you use JDK 1.6.
Additionally, JHipster requires JDK 8 so the solution is to upgrade to JDK 8.

If you're on Mac OSX check [Installed Java 7 on Mac OS X but Terminal is still using version 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757558/installed-java-7-on-mac-os-x-but-terminal-is-still-using-version-6/14875241#14875241)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I installed JDK9 (I had 8 actually, but still...) . Java - version is giving me : 
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)  and I still have the error, is it normal?

Comment: JHipster does not support JDK 9. Which OS?