# Installing Java on OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)

Tags: java, macos

I have installed the [JDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) on [Mac OS X v10.8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mountain_Lion) (Mountain Lion). When I upgraded it to [Mac OS X v10.9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (Mavericks) and ran `java -version` in the terminal, it showed:

> No Java runtime present, requesting install.

Then I manually installed the JDK (1.7) on my Mac. It seems that the installation worked fine. When the installation was done, I opened the terminal and typed `java -version` as well. It also showed the same error:

> No Java runtime present, requesting install.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know what problem is there in terminal but I run eclipse and all projects are compiling fine in mavericks

Comment: Do you see Java in the preferences ?

Comment: it seems the old java launcher only support jdk 1.6 but mavericks doesn't have 1.6 installed by default.

Comment: java -version command is running fine on mavericks. It was already installed in mountain lion. and there is no java option in system  preference.

Comment: You installed java 6, not java 7 as OP originally implied they needed. I am interested in how that solution is reached. Also there must be an 'alternatives' kind of approach here that directly addresses the feedback from the terminal.

Comment: This is great for Java 6, but how can you get Java 7 to work?

Comment: Added a potential answer to install the Java 7 JRE and have it working in the Terminal: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19582689/346286

Comment: @user2909913 You should remove the update part of the question and select the correct answer as accepted instead.

Comment: It is incredible to me that what claims to be a modern operating system needs so much hand-holding.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

The new *Mavericks* (10.9) showed me the "Requesting install", but nothing happened.

The solution was to manually download and install the official Java package for OS X, which is in <del>*[Java for OS X 2013-005](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1421)*</del>.

**Update:** As mentioned in the comments below, there is a newer version of this same package:

<del>[Java for OS X 2014-001](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572)</del>

*[Java for OS X 2014-001](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572)* (Correcting dead line above)

> Java for OS X 2014-001 includes installation improvements, and supersedes all previous versions of Java for OS X. This package installs the same version of Java 6 included in Java for OS X 2013-005.

Comment: Same for me. Another choice is to install Java from Oracle. Which one do you guys think is better? Oracle seems to have Java updated more quickly than Apple.

Comment: but this one gives you JDK 6. how can we use JDK 6 directly?

Comment: @Shawn Apple disables already installed JDK 7. But you can get some FAQ and  install from here: https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml but i did not try it out.

Comment: If you have installed both java6 and java7, you can select v6 in your shell with: export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: If you want header files for compiling JNI modules or want to have the  javadocs, you would need to download and install "Java for OS X 2013-005 Developer Package" from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

Comment: @mtomy 32-bit on OS X 10.9? don't think so. They might only include the 64 bit version. see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html#install

Comment: Why would you want to use 32 bit java on a 64bit OS? 64 bit java is actually faster than 32bit under Mavericks.

Comment: The link they direct you to in the popup doesn't work but this one does.  Mind.  Blown.

Comment: Hope apple dont remove the java 6 version, need that for some legacy apps that dont work well with newer JVMs due to reliance on sun java classes (that should not be used but need to for some obscure reason)

Comment: Also see [HT202912, About Java for OS X 2014-001](http://support.apple.com/no-no/HT202912)" *"This article is about older, unsupported Java software. Download the latest version of Java for OS X directly from Oracle."* The older version its discussing is Java for OS X 2014-001. Are you sure your answer applies to Mavericks?

Answer (score 197):

If you only want to install the latest official JRE from Oracle, you can get it there, install it, and export the new JAVA_HOME in the terminal.

- Open your Terminal
- `java -version` gives you an error and a popup
- Get the JRE dmg on http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
- Install it
- In your terminal, type: `export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home"`
- `java -version` now gives you `java version "1.7.0_45"`

That's the cleanest way I found to install the latest JRE.

You can add the `export JAVA_HOME` line in your `.bashrc` to have `java` permanently in your Terminal:

```
echo export JAVA_HOME=\"/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home\" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: For Maverics Update the the file is at ~/.bash_profile. Once that is updated with the path above - restart your terminal to see your changes.

Comment: I think it sounds a little fishy to define `JAVA_HOME` to point at what is clearly a browser plugin instead of the real VM. When you install the XCode command line tools, you get a tool for getting the correct path, `/usr/libexec/java_home`. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/java_home.1.html.

Comment: @Ilkka - it does sound fishy, but that's actually where Oracle's JRE installs to. Apple's java (which stops at java 6) doesn't mix with oracle's quite as nicely as one might like

Comment: A colleague of mine (who unfortunately does not have the required reputation here to add comments) wants to add that the JAVA_HOME setting should be `export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home"`

Comment: I installed jdk7u45 from Oracle and still use 
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) in my bash profile. jdk7u45 works very nicely including the java system preference panel.

Now I'm upgrading to jdk7u51.

Comment: I am talking about the JRE here, not the JDK

Comment: @analogue Correct but the OP is asking about the JDK

Comment: I had to add `export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home"` to ~/.profile instead of ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile to get this work.

Comment: @Ilkka Doesn't detect JRE8 anymore.

Comment: where is it installed?

Comment: How do I give you money? Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 64):

The right place to download the JDK for Java 7 is *[Java SE Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)*.

All the other links provided above, as far as I can tell, either provide the JRE or Java 6 downloads (incidentally, if you want to run [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) or other IDEs, like [IntelliJ IDEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA), you will need the JDK, *not* the [JRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine#Execution_environment)).

Regarding IntelliJ IDEA - that will still ask you to install Java 6 as it apparently needs an older class loader or something: just follow the instructions when the dialog pop-up appears and it will install the JDK 6 in the right place.

Afterwards, you will need to do the `sudo ln -snf` mentioned in the answer above:

```
sudo ln -nsf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents \
    /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK
```

(copied here as it was mentioned that "above" may eventually not make sense as answers are re-sorted).

I also set my `JAVA_HOME` to point to where `jdk_1.7.0_xx.jdk` was installed:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Then add that to your `PATH`:

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

The alternative is to fuzz around with Apple's insane maze of hyperlinks, but honestly life is too short to bother.

Comment: See [my comment to another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533528/installing-java-on-os-x-10-9-mavericks#comment29812677_19582689) for what is perhaps a better way to get that path.

Comment: Since this answer has more upvotes, the bit that says `sudo ln -snf` in the answer above is not accurate anymore. That is actually referring to the answer by [Mr. Ronald](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19729259/399435)

Comment: @KarthicRaghupathi I'm not sure I fully understand the comment (the use of `this` and `that` is somewhat confusing) but you still need a symlink from the /Sytem/Library/etc place to the actual place where Oracle installs the JVM (/Library/etc.) or applications will be unable to find the Java runtime.

Comment: @Marco Now that you mention it, when I read my own comment, it does not really make much sense. :) Allow me to clarify. In your answer, you write "Afterwards, you will need to do the `sudo ln -snf` mentioned in the answer above;". Answers move up or down based on the number of up votes they get. My intention was to only provide a direct reference to the answer that had the `sudo ln -snf` command.

Comment: Edited - but not actually sure that the re-ordering really happens: they all seem to be where they were, regardless of upvotes. NVM

Comment: If you instead set `JAVA_HOME="/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home"` then it will still be correct if/when you upgrade your JDK.

Comment: @Peter - I'm not sure that that would work (in fact, I'm almost sure it won't): it assumes that the "insane maze of hyperlinks" is correctly set, and, as I mentioned, life is too short...

Comment: @Marco, it does work (or my installation would be broken, which it isn't) and we are actually talking about symbolic file links, not hyperlinks.

Comment: Intellij 13 CE runs fine on Oracle jdk7u46 64bit on my OS X Mavericks 10.9.1 machine. I don't have java 6 installed and did not have to do any hacking to get this to work. Some older apps with java 6 library dependencies doesn't work, but java development (Eclipse) is significantly faster and better than on jdk 6. 

If you're a developer use jdk7 and upgrade your code base if needed.

Comment: Eclipse brings its own compiler and can run on a JRE.  Netbeans and Idea require a full JDK.

Answer (score 14):

I downloaded and installed the JDK 1.7 from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html). In the console / in [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_%28OS_X%29) Java 7 works fine.

When I start a Java program (like [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29)) via the GUI, I get:

> To open "Eclipse.app" you need a Java SE 6 runtime. Would you like to
>   install one now?

Because I did not want to install old Java version, I used the following workaround:

`sudo ln -nsf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK`

Credits to [monkehWorks](http://www.monkehworks.com/set-java-7-as-default-jvm-on-mac-osx-mountain-lion).

Comment: I need to use `ln -snf` because I got `Operation not permitted` with `ln -sf`

Comment: Thx, I edited the answer and added the -n option to the ln command.

Comment: +1 Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! The CLI was getting the reference to JDK 7 after installation. However for getting the GUI apps to pickup the correct JDK this step was necessary.

Comment: Was hopeful, but it didn't work for me. Android Studio 0.3.2 insists on "downloading Java 6" which I'm not going to do. Oracle Java 7 JDK is installed.

Comment: You need a 64-bit version of Eclipse.  The 32-bit requires Apple java.

Comment: @Mr.Ronald For me after `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents` the paths do not exist, is that normal? do I proceed anyways?

Answer (score 4):

This error happens because the plist file of IntelliJ IDEA requires Java version 1.6*. To solve this problem, replace the 1.6* with 1.8*.

```
<key>JVMOptions</key>
<dict>
    <key>ClassPath</key>
      ...

    <key>JVMVersion</key>
    <string>1.8*</string>

    <key>MainClass</key>
    <string>com.intellij.idea.Main</string>
    <key>Properties</key>
<dict>
```

Comment: This did it for me. My problem was when I updated to osx 10.9, I could still access java from the terminal and everything else (including eclipse worked fine). Only Android Studio was causing this error.

Comment: This didn't work for me on OS X 10.10.1, it complains that no version 1.8 is available (even if the JRE 8 is properly installed).

Comment: Did you check if JAVA_HOME is set?

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded manually to here: [Java for OS X 2014-001](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572).

After that open your terminal and check the installation with `java -version`.

**EDIT (January, 2015)**: Also see [HT202912, About Java for OS X 2014-001](http://support.apple.com/no-no/HT202912):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The OP implied that Java 7 was the need. And Java 6 is in fact no longer being 'supported' so 7 is the version you should be installing at this point unless you have legacy app concerns.

You can get it here:
http://java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp?locale=en

Comment: We should not assume that Apple's current distribution of Java 6 is unsupported.

Comment: I placed the word 'supported' in quotes so as to avoid trying to tease out a complicated issue.  Oracle charges for any support of 6... and that support charge would logically apply to Apple, as well; so, Apple is 'on its own' without a contract. Do they have one, *and* plan to work thru the patches for MacOSX? Does the contract still allow for re-distribution? Now there have been 2 Java 7 updates from Oracle since Apple's last update to 6. Historically, they tend to lock-step releases. Assumption, perhaps; A safe assumption? Seems so.

Answer (score 3):

My experience for updating Java SDK on OS X 10.9 was much easier.

I downloaded the latest `Java SE Development Kit 8`, from [SE downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and installed the .dmg file. And when typing `java -version` in terminal the following was displayed:

> java version "1.8.0_11"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1):

From the OP:

I finally reinstalled it from Java for OS X 2013-005.  It solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This error means Java is not properly installed .

```
1) brew cask install java (No need to install cask separately it comes with brew)

2) java -version

java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
```

P.S - What is brew-cask ? Homebrew-Cask extends Homebrew , and solves the hassle of executing an extra command - *“To install, drag this icon…”* after installing a Application using *Homebrew*.

N.B - This problem is not specific to Mavericks , you will get it almost all the OS X, including EL Capitan.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any need to install the JDK, which is the *developer kit*, just the [JRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine#Execution_environment) which is the *runtime environment*.

Comment: That's true. However, what Apple provide is the JDK and the JRE from Oracle is just there for the Internet Plugin, the `java` command is not linked system-wide automatically so you still see the "No Java runtime present, requesting install." when you type `java -version` in the Terminal.