# Webserver not working on OSX Mavericks

Tags: coldfusion, webserver, osx-mavericks, coldfusion-10

I was running a webserver and also Coldfusion just fine until I upgraded to Mountain Lion, then it stopped working. I got it working again by turning everything back on that the upgrade disabled, but now I have upgraded to Mavericks nothing is working. I have followed all the steps in various web articles but it won't work. PHP is enabled, everything that was enabled before is set up, including virtual hosts, and all the folders are in the same place.

I get the error: Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1. [or localhost, or any of my virtual hosts]

I've gone over everything time after time and I can't figure out why it won't work. I have started, stopped, restarted the webserver numerous times, it is set to start on bootup too. I couldn't even complete the Coldfusion install because I couldn't load the administrator in a browser.

What could the problem be? Where should I look?

Comment: There's an open [bug report](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3653076) for this but there's a solution listed in the comments on that page.

Comment: This question is better suited for ServerFault

Comment: Oh well that explains everything! I couldn't figure out what I was missing here. Hmmm... so wait for Adobe or abandon ColdFusion. Great.

Comment: The Adobe bug shows as fixed, the update will be part of patch 13, when that will be released I'm not sure, and how we'll apply it, with no working admin I'm not sure. I think sit tight for now. I am currently using the in-built CF server as a temp workaround for CF pages

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but this should help get things started

Try using the command line start. It will probably be complaining about Java 7 not being installed. I recently needed to install Java 7 JDK (not JRE to get things running)

[image]

I know to get the rest of it running, I need to point ColdFusion at the proper JVM. You can find the JVM settings at `/Applications/ColdFusion10/cfusion/bin/jvm.xml`. You should have some setting like

```
# VM configuration
#
# Where to find JVM, if {java.home}/jre exists then that JVM is used
# if not then it must be the path to the JRE itself

java.home=/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
application.home=/Applications/ColdFusion10/cfusion
```

When you install Java 7, the JRE is at

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre`

Backup, and edit the jvm.config file to

```
#
# VM configuration
#
# Where to find JVM, if {java.home}/jre exists then that JVM is used
# if not then it must be the path to the JRE itself

java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
# java.home=/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
application.home=/Applications/ColdFusion10/cfusion
```

If all goes well, you should be able to start ColdFusion

[image]

**Some additional help**

[Installing Java on OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533528/installing-java-on-os-x-10-9-mavericks)

When you install Java 7

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this thread. ColdFusion 10 is now supported on OS X 10.9 Maverick with the release of [CF10 Update 13](http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/coldfusion-10-update-13-released).

This should work for you now.