# Can't update Coldfusion to Java 1.7 on OSX 10.9

Tags: java, macos, coldfusion

Running OSX 10.9.3 with ColdFusion 9.0.1. Was running on Java 1.6 and now trying to update to Java 1.7. I've updated CF with the proper hotfix for 1.7 compatibility. I installed the 64-bit 1.7 JDK as well.

Now I have Java in two places:

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk
```

When I run

```
java -version
```

I get java

```
version "1.7.0_60" 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

but when I restart CF it comes up and reports

```
Java Version    1.6.0_65  
Java Vendor     Apple Inc.  
Java Vendor URL     http://www.apple.com/
Java Home   /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I changed the symlink in

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
```

to

```
CurrentJDK@ -> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/
```

but a CF restart still reports Apple's 1.6. I also tried updating the jvm.config and setting java.home (which was previously blank) to

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
```

and a restart and still no luck. Where is CF looking for the JVM and how to make CF see 1.7?

Comment: Not really a question about programming. Better suited for Server Fault

Comment: Consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366358/webserver-not-working-on-osx-mavericks/20367252#20367252

Comment: Still no luck. Set JAVA_HOME in bash profile. Updated JAVA_HOME in /bin/coldfusion /bin/jvm.config and /runtime/bin/usconfig_jvm.config and still no luck. Starts up fine but still reports 1.6. I have no idea where the CF server is looking for the JVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted a similar question [Why can't I update Java from 1.6 to 1.7 on Coldfusion 9.0.2 on Mac OSX 10.8.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942062/why-cant-i-update-java-from-1-6-to-1-7-on-coldfusion-9-0-2-on-mac-osx-10-8-5) but had no luck.

This answer below according to Adobe: (See comments 40-41). It appears that this configuration is not supported by Adobe. Time to upgrade (or move to OBD/PHP).

http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/new-updates-for-coldfusion-9-9-0-1-9-0-2-and-10-java-7-now-supported